# Truncate number to two decimal places without rounding

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a value of 15.7784514, I want to display it 15.77 with no rounding.

```
var num = parseFloat(15.7784514);
document.write(num.toFixed(1)+"<br />");
document.write(num.toFixed(2)+"<br />");
document.write(num.toFixed(3)+"<br />");
document.write(num.toFixed(10));
```

Results in -

```
15.8
15.78
15.778
15.7784514000
```

How do I display 15.77?

Comment: It's useful when displaying currency.

Comment: @ mik01aj - When displaying currency, it is more common to truncate calculated values, rather than rounding them.  For example, most tax forms in the US truncate rather than round calculated fractional cents.  In that case, the truncated value is the correct value.

Comment: Simpler solution:
[Truncate to decimals function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184500/2086460)

Comment: I have no idea why you would want to run `parseFloat` on a float. It's already a float, so no need to parse it. So - do you initially have a `string` or a `number`?

Comment: @CamiloMartin there is a huge difference between a debt of 1.49 billion dollars and 1.0 billion dollars.

Comment: There is also a huge difference between 1.49 billion and 1.50 billion dollars. That's $100 million.

Comment: If you round $1.49B of currency, you could end up telling someone they have $1.5B.  They will be disappointed at checkout, and will have to remove $1.5B 'Eclipse' Luxury Mega Yacht from cart.

Comment: can i just do this `15.7784514.toFixed(3).slice(0, -1)` call it a day?

Answer (score 286, accepted):

Convert the number into a string, match the number up to the second decimal place:

```js
function calc(theform) {
    var num = theform.original.value, rounded = theform.rounded
    var with2Decimals = num.toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/)[0]
    rounded.value = with2Decimals
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return calc(this)">
Original number: <input name="original" type="text" onkeyup="calc(form)" onchange="calc(form)" />
<br />"Rounded" number: <input name="rounded" type="text" placeholder="readonly" readonly>
</form>
```

The `toFixed` method fails in some cases unlike `toString`, so be very careful with it.

Comment: +1 That should solve the rounding issue. I'd still output the result of the above using `toFixed`, though, so: `(Math.floor(value * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)`. As you probably know, weird precision things can happen with floating point values (and on the other side of the spectrum, if the number happens to be `15`, sounds like the OP wants `15.00`).

Comment: hehe, or if you combine both: `Number((15.7784514000*100).toString().match(/^\d+/)/100);`

Comment: Math.floor(value * 100) / 100
won't work if value = 4.27
seriously, try it.

Comment: @DarkHippo Thats because 4.27 is actually 4.26999999999, Math.round is generally a better solution, albeit not the answer to the original question. Realistically given the output is a string this should be done using string manipulation instead of a numeric solution with all the floating point foibles.

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? There are serious problems with the `Math.floor(15.7784514000 * 100) / 100` approach. If you have a multiplication inside a Math.floor() function it WILL FAIL for some numbers! Floating point arithmetic is NOT ACCURATE and you need to use different methods, such as the RegEx. Stop upvoting this answer you're spreading bad code around. As mentioned above try `4.27` in that function and it will fail.

Comment: ...that doesn't sound right. Converting between types under any circumstances seems roundabout and unsafe. Unless a really advanced programmer would argue that "all types are just streams" or something.

Comment: Unfortunately, try `0.00000001990202020291` and you'll get `1.99`. The issue is that if you just return that long decimal JS turns it into `1.99020202029e-8` first and I don't know how to get around that. Does anyone have any suggestions @IvanCastellanos

Comment: `theform.original.value` is **already** a `string`. Why do you need to `toString()` it?

Comment: Is there a way to always show 2 decimals with this solution? 
Like toFixed kind of thing.

Comment: it fails if we don't add any value before decimal i.e .9

Comment: @AnubhavGupta To make it work without values before the decimal just change the + in the regex into as * so you get: `match(/^-?\d*(?:\.\d{0,2})?/) `

Comment: How to keep precision value in a variable? like match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0, "here variable" })?/)[0]

Comment: I want to truncate this number: `99999999999999.9999` to 4 decimal places but it results in: `100000000000000.0000`, please help me out?

Answer (score 108):

## Update 5 Nov 2016

### New answer, always accurate

```
function toFixed(num, fixed) {
    var re = new RegExp('^-?\\d+(?:\.\\d{0,' + (fixed || -1) + '})?');
    return num.toString().match(re)[0];
}
```

As [floating point math in javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) will always have edge cases, the previous solution will be accurate most of the time which is not good enough.
There are some solutions to this like `num.toPrecision`, [BigDecimal.js](https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js), and [accounting.js](https://github.com/openexchangerates/accounting.js).
Yet, I believe that merely parsing the string will be the simplest and always accurate.

Basing the update on the well written regex from the accepted answer by @Gumbo, this new toFixed function will always work as expected.

---

### Old answer, not always accurate.

Roll your own toFixed function:

```
function toFixed(num, fixed) {
    fixed = fixed || 0;
    fixed = Math.pow(10, fixed);
    return Math.floor(num * fixed) / fixed;
}
```

Comment: toFixed(4.56, 2) = 4.55

Comment: So many of these answers have a multiplication inside a Math.floor() function. This will fail for some numbers! Floating point arithmetic is not accurate and you need to use different methods.

Comment: function toFixedCustom(num, fixed) {
              var re = new RegExp('^-?\\d+(?:\.\\d{0,' + (fixed || -1) + '})?');
              if(num.toString().match(re) ){
                  return num.toString().match(re)[0];
              }
             }

Comment: The updated answer will fail for a number big or small enough that javascript would represent in scientific notation. `toFixed(0.0000000052, 2)` yields '5.2'. This can be fixed by using `return num.toFixed(fixed+1).match(re)[0];` Notice I'm using toFixed with one decimal place above the target to avoid rounding, then running your regex match

Comment: @guya, I'm pretty sure -0.001 will return -0.00. I think in most cases you will want either 0 or 0.00 without the negative symbol.

Comment: Please DO NOT use the to fixed version, eg: if a = 10.20, a * 100 returns 1019.9999999

Comment: @George, use the **New answer, always accurate** `toFixed(10.20, 2)` returns `10.2`

Answer (score 82):

Another single-line solution :

```
number = Math.trunc(number*100)/100
```

I used 100 because you want to truncate to the second digit, but a more flexible solution would be :

```
number = Math.trunc(number*Math.pow(10, digits))/Math.pow(10, digits)
```

where digits is the amount of decimal digits to keep.

See [Math.trunc specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) for details and browser compatibility.

Comment: This is the best answer if you do not have to support IE11.

Comment: @T.Junghans Sorry but this doesn't work: (4.27, 2) => 4.26  and that happens regardless of IE11 or any other browser.

Comment: it's the year 2023 and `Math.trunc(number*100)/100` totally works - was using it on lat lng values (ins SAFARI (the new IE) no less) and it delivered 

Comment: Thank you, @ingdc! Indeed, it does not work. The same with `Math.floor()`.

Answer (score 53):

I opted to write this instead to manually remove the remainder with strings so I don't have to deal with the math issues that come with numbers:

```
num = num.toString(); //If it's not already a String
num = num.slice(0, (num.indexOf("."))+3); //With 3 exposing the hundredths place
Number(num); //If you need it back as a Number
```

This will give you "15.77" with num = 15.7784514;

Comment: If you're not forcing a decimal, you may want to add a conditional in case you encounter whole numbers.  Like this: num = num.toString(); if(num.indexOf(".") > 0){num = num.slice(0, (num.indexOf("."))+3)}; Number(num);

Comment: nice if it has decimals but if it's an integer it will fail

Comment: If the num is 0.00000052, then it will be wrong getting 5.2e

Comment: @Vasanth If the number is 0.00000052 it returns "0.00". Maybe the answer has been edited since

Comment: Yeah, it fails in edge cases

Answer (score 32):

## Update (Jan 2021)

Depending on its range, a number in javascript may be shown in scientific notation. For example, if you type 0.0000001 in the console, you may see it as 1e-7, whereas 0.000001 appears unchanged (0.000001).
If your application works on a range of numbers for which scientific notation is not involved, you can just ignore this update and use the original answer below.

This update is about adding a function that checks if the number is in scientific format and, if so, converts it into decimal format. Here I'm proposing this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript), but you can use any other function that achieves the same goal, according to your application's needs:

```
function toFixed(x) {
  if (Math.abs(x) < 1.0) {
    let e = parseInt(x.toString().split('e-')[1]);
    if (e) {
        x *= Math.pow(10,e-1);
        x = '0.' + (new Array(e)).join('0') + x.toString().substring(2);
    }
  } else {
    let e = parseInt(x.toString().split('+')[1]);
    if (e > 20) {
        e -= 20;
        x /= Math.pow(10,e);
        x += (new Array(e+1)).join('0');
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

Now just apply that function to the parameter (that's the only change with respect to the original answer):

```
function toFixedTrunc(x, n) {
      x = toFixed(x) 

      // From here on the code is the same than the original answer
      const v = (typeof x === 'string' ? x : x.toString()).split('.');
      if (n <= 0) return v[0];
      let f = v[1] || '';
      if (f.length > n) return `${v[0]}.${f.substr(0,n)}`;
      while (f.length < n) f += '0';
      return `${v[0]}.${f}`
    }
```

This updated version addresses also a case mentioned in a comment:

```
toFixedTrunc(0.000000199, 2) => "0.00"
```

Again, choose what fits your application needs at best.

## Original answer (October 2017)

General solution to truncate (no rounding) a number to the n-th decimal digit and convert it to a string with exactly n decimal digits, for any n≥0.

```
function toFixedTrunc(x, n) {
  const v = (typeof x === 'string' ? x : x.toString()).split('.');
  if (n <= 0) return v[0];
  let f = v[1] || '';
  if (f.length > n) return `${v[0]}.${f.substr(0,n)}`;
  while (f.length < n) f += '0';
  return `${v[0]}.${f}`
}
```

where x can be either a number (which gets converted into a string) or a string.

Here are some tests for n=2 (including the one requested by OP):

```
0           => 0.00
0.01        => 0.01
0.5839      => 0.58
0.999       => 0.99
1.01        => 1.01
2           => 2.00
2.551       => 2.55
2.99999     => 2.99
4.27        => 4.27
15.7784514  => 15.77
123.5999    => 123.59
```

And for some other values of n:

```
15.001097   => 15.0010 (n=4)
0.000003298 => 0.0000032 (n=7)
0.000003298257899 => 0.000003298257 (n=12)
```

Comment: `toFixedTrunc(0.000000199, 2) // 1.99 `

Comment: SC1000, I’m not sure how to interpret your answer to @Maharramoff. Are you saying that because there’s an explanation as to why your code sometimes fails, the code is correct? Or are you saying that 1.99 is the proper result of truncating 0.000000199 to 2 decimal places?

Comment: @SC1000 You’re just explaining why your approach fails. The problem is your assumption that numbers would only have one possible string representation, and that this representation would be “0.000000199” for 0.000000199. If the language doesn’t guarantee that, relying on it is a mistake.

Comment: @Maharramoff and others interested in the toFixedTrunc(0.000000199, 2) case, please refer to the updated answer (Jan 2021). Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! Though, just in case, `toFixed(), 0.0000001 -> 1e-7 -> 0.00000009999999999999999`, and the reason is in general: `0.000001 * 100 ~= 0.00009999999999999999`.

Answer (score 14):

parseInt is faster then Math.floor

```
function floorFigure(figure, decimals){
    if (!decimals) decimals = 2;
    var d = Math.pow(10,decimals);
    return (parseInt(figure*d)/d).toFixed(decimals);
};

floorFigure(123.5999)    =>   "123.59"
floorFigure(123.5999, 3) =>   "123.599"
```

Comment: it fails with 1234567.89

Comment: Could you elaborate Lopez?

Comment: floorFigure(4.56, 2) = 4.55

Answer (score 12):

```
num = 19.66752
f = num.toFixed(3).slice(0,-1)
alert(f)
```

This will return 19.66

Comment: (4.9999).toFixed(3).slice(0, -1) returns 5.00, expected result is 4.99.

Comment: I recommend using something like .toFixed(6).slice(0, -4) instead.

Comment: that's perfect, in my case it woks ok. for example if I want to have just one decimal number use num.toFixed(2).slice(0,-1)   ( if num has 1.2356, it'll return 1.2)

Comment: This is bad because in case that the 3th number was 9 it will round also the 2nd number

Comment: js is messed up, why is 8.2 * 100 => 819.99999999

Answer (score 10):

Simple do this

```
number = parseInt(number * 100)/100;
```

Comment: parseInt(8.2*100) = 819

Comment: This answer isn't the elegantest one, but is the cleanest and it works very well.

Answer (score 8):

### Updated in 2023

There is one problem that no one has addressed: **What to do with negative zeros ?**

Should toFixed_norounding(-0.0000001, 2) be "-0.00" or "0.00" ?
In my application it is preferred to make it "0.00"

I created this updated version for negative and positive numbers, with tests, uncomment if you need negative zeros:

```
function toFixed_norounding(n,p)
{
    var result = n.toFixed(p);
    result = Math.abs(result) <= Math.abs(n) ? result: (result - Math.sign(n) * Math.pow(0.1,p)).toFixed(p);

    // if you want negative zeros (-0.00), use this instead:
    // return result;

    // fixes negative zeros:
    if(result == 0) return (0).toFixed(p);
    else return result;
}

// tests:
[
    ["-1.99", -1.999999999999999,2],
    ["1.99", 1.999999999999999,2],
    ["-1.9", -1.999999999999999,1],
    ["1.9", 1.999999999999999,1],
    ["-1", -1.999999999999999,0],
    ["1", 1.999999999999999,0],
    ["4.56", 4.56, 2],
    ["-4.56", -4.56, 2],
    ["0.00", 0.00000000052, 2],
    //["-0.00", -0.00000000052, 2], // allow negative zeros
    ["0.00", -0.00000000052, 2], // don't
    ["0.00", 0.000000000, 2],
    ["0.00", -0.000000000, 2],
    ["4.27", 4.27, 2],
    ["-4.27", -4.27, 2],
    ["0.00", 0.000000199, 2],
    //["-0.00", -0.000000199, 2], // allow negative zeros
    ["0.00", -0.000000199, 2], // don't
    ["1234567.89", 1234567.89, 2],
    ["-1234567.89", -1234567.89, 2],
    ["4.999", 4.9999, 3],
    ["-4.999", -4.9999, 3],
].forEach( a => {
    if(!( a[0] === toFixed_norounding(a[1],a[2]) )) console.log("test failed:", a, "result: ", toFixed_norounding(a[1],a[2]));
});
```

Fast, pretty, obvious.

Comment: needed a non-rounding for float values (e.g. money), with only 1 decimal. The above function should be the "answer" of this topic, it's excellent, works like a charm. cheers to the author & thanks. :)))

Comment: Failed for negative value. `-0.7752`. Test it  `toFixed_norounding(-0.7752,2)` returns `-0.78` instead of `-0.77`

Comment: Ling Loeng, fixed.

Comment: toFixed_norounding(0.11111111111111125, 17) -> 0.11111111111111124

Answer (score 8):

Just truncate the digits:

```
function truncDigits(inputNumber, digits) {
  const fact = 10 ** digits;
  return Math.floor(inputNumber * fact) / fact;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Of course you can add this to prototype:
`Number.prototype.truncDigits = function (digits) {
    const fact = 10 ** digits;
    return Math.floor(this.valueOf() * fact) / fact;
  }`.
So you can use it as: `num.truncDigits(3)`

Comment: Just in case, `const f = 10 ** 2; Math.floor(4.27 * f) / f; // 4.26`, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48100007/5113030

Answer (score 8):

**This is not a safe alternative, as many others commented examples with numbers that turn into exponential notation, that scenery is not covered by this function**

```js
// typescript
// function formatLimitDecimals(value: number, decimals: number): number {

function formatLimitDecimals(value, decimals) { 
  const stringValue = value.toString();
  if(stringValue.includes('e')) {
      // TODO: remove exponential notation
      throw 'invald number';
  } else {
    const [integerPart, decimalPart] = stringValue.split('.');
    if(decimalPart) {
      return +[integerPart, decimalPart.slice(0, decimals)].join('.')
    } else {
      return integerPart;
    }
  }
}

console.log(formatLimitDecimals(4.156, 2)); // 4.15
console.log(formatLimitDecimals(4.156, 8)); // 4.156
console.log(formatLimitDecimals(4.156, 0)); // 4
console.log(formatLimitDecimals(0, 4)); // 0

// not covered
console.log(formatLimitDecimals(0.000000199, 2)); // 0.00
```

Answer (score 7):

I fixed using following simple way-

```
var num = 15.7784514;
Math.floor(num*100)/100;
```

Results will be **15.77**

Comment: It doesn't work with negative values: `-15.7784514` returns `-15.78`

Comment: Math.floor(39.37*100)/100; = 39.36 which is not right.

Answer (score 6):

These solutions do work, but to me seem unnecessarily complicated.  I personally like to use the modulus operator to obtain the remainder of a division operation, and remove that.  Assuming that num = 15.7784514:

```
num-=num%.01;
```

This is equivalent to saying num = num - (num % .01).

Comment: That's interesting Nijkokun, thanks for pointing it out.  I've never run into problems using this technique, but clearly I should take a closer look for instances like this.  As an alternative you could use ((num*=100)-(num%1))/100 which resolves this issue.  The priority in my case is execution speed because of the volume of calculations I'm applying this to, and this is the fastest way of achieving this that I've found.

Comment: The point was to avoid the object and function lookups and conversions required in the other solutions offered.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: also fails with negatives as -5

Comment: I'm also interested in a fast rounding, how would you make this code do 1 decimal?

Comment: HI thanks about very intellegant sulotion. But it doesn't work if number shorter then required round:
`a = 1.2585;
a -= a % .00001;
a` now is `1.25849`

Answer (score 5):

The answers here didn't help me, it kept rounding up or giving me the wrong decimal.

my solution converts your decimal to a string, extracts the characters and then returns the whole thing as a number.

```
function Dec2(num) {
  num = String(num);
  if(num.indexOf('.') !== -1) {
    var numarr = num.split(".");
    if (numarr.length == 1) {
      return Number(num);
    }
    else {
      return Number(numarr[0]+"."+numarr[1].charAt(0)+numarr[1].charAt(1));
    }
  }
  else {
    return Number(num);
  }  
}

Dec2(99); // 99
Dec2(99.9999999); // 99.99
Dec2(99.35154); // 99.35
Dec2(99.8); // 99.8
Dec2(10265.985475); // 10265.98
```

Comment: Dec2(99) should return 99.00

Answer (score 5):

This worked well for me. I hope it will fix your issues too.

```
function toFixedNumber(number) {
    const spitedValues = String(number.toLocaleString()).split('.');
    let decimalValue = spitedValues.length > 1 ? spitedValues[1] : '';
    decimalValue = decimalValue.concat('00').substr(0,2);

    return '$'+spitedValues[0] + '.' + decimalValue;
}

// 5.56789      ---->  $5.56
// 0.342        ---->  $0.34
// -10.3484534  ---->  $-10.34 
// 600          ---->  $600.00
```

```js
function convertNumber(){
  var result = toFixedNumber(document.getElementById("valueText").value);
  document.getElementById("resultText").value = result;
}


function toFixedNumber(number) {
        const spitedValues = String(number.toLocaleString()).split('.');
        let decimalValue = spitedValues.length > 1 ? spitedValues[1] : '';
        decimalValue = decimalValue.concat('00').substr(0,2);

        return '$'+spitedValues[0] + '.' + decimalValue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="valueText" placeholder="Input value here..">
  <br>
  <button onclick="convertNumber()" >Convert</button>
  <br><hr>
  <input type="text" id="resultText" placeholder="result" readonly="true">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function limitDecimalsWithoutRounding(val, decimals){
    let parts = val.toString().split(".");
    return parseFloat(parts[0] + "." + parts[1].substring(0, decimals));
}

var num = parseFloat(15.7784514);
var new_num = limitDecimalsWithoutRounding(num, 2);
```

Answer (score 4):

The following code works very good for me:

```
num.toString().match(/.\*\\..{0,2}|.\*/)[0];
```

Comment: I will add the optional minus sign to make it perfect `-?` ;)

Answer (score 4):

An Easy way to do it is the next but is necessary ensure that the amount parameter is given as a string.

```
function truncate(amountAsString, decimals = 2){
  var dotIndex = amountAsString.indexOf('.');
  var toTruncate = dotIndex !== -1  && ( amountAsString.length > dotIndex + decimals + 1);
  var approach = Math.pow(10, decimals);
  var amountToTruncate = toTruncate ? amountAsString.slice(0, dotIndex + decimals +1) : amountAsString;  
  return toTruncate
    ?  Math.floor(parseFloat(amountToTruncate) * approach ) / approach
    :  parseFloat(amountAsString);
```

}

```
console.log(truncate("7.99999")); //OUTPUT ==> 7.99
console.log(truncate("7.99999", 3)); //OUTPUT ==> 7.999
console.log(truncate("12.799999999999999")); //OUTPUT ==> 7.99
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you are. An answer that shows yet another way to solve the problem:

```
// For the sake of simplicity, here is a complete function:
function truncate(numToBeTruncated, numOfDecimals) {
    var theNumber = numToBeTruncated.toString();
    var pointIndex = theNumber.indexOf('.');
    return +(theNumber.slice(0, pointIndex > -1 ? ++numOfDecimals + pointIndex : undefined));
}
```

Note the use of + before the final expression. That is to convert our truncated, sliced string back to number type.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I like the simplicity of this approach, and I feel that all the solutions that avoid using Maths, are more appropriate for solving this problem. So, the use of slice() etc, is the correct way forward. The only advantage of my method is that it will process numbers passed in that are strings [surrounded by quote marks [single/double]]. For some reason, the function above threw an error in FF, when I did: console.log('truncate("0.85156",2)',truncate("0.85156",2));

Answer (score 3):

truncate without zeroes

```
function toTrunc(value,n){  
    return Math.floor(value*Math.pow(10,n))/(Math.pow(10,n));
}
```

or

```
function toTrunc(value,n){
    x=(value.toString()+".0").split(".");
    return parseFloat(x[0]+"."+x[1].substr(0,n));
}
```

test:

```
toTrunc(17.4532,2)  //17.45
toTrunc(177.4532,1) //177.4
toTrunc(1.4532,1)   //1.4
toTrunc(.4,2)       //0.4
```

truncate with zeroes

```
function toTruncFixed(value,n){
    return toTrunc(value,n).toFixed(n);
}
```

test:

```
toTrunc(17.4532,2)  //17.45
toTrunc(177.4532,1) //177.4
toTrunc(1.4532,1)   //1.4
toTrunc(.4,2)       //0.40
```

Answer (score 3):

If you exactly wanted to truncate to 2 digits of precision, you can go with a simple logic:

```
function myFunction(number) {
  var roundedNumber = number.toFixed(2);
  if (roundedNumber > number)
  {
      roundedNumber = roundedNumber - 0.01;
  }
  return roundedNumber;
}
```

Comment: This results in the subtraction problem and generates incorrect results.

Comment: The OP has given cases with positive floating point number not integers. Javascript doesn't give correct results when 0.01 is subtracted from a floating point number. For example, if you run 2.37 - 0.01 in your browser console, the answer you will get will be 2.3600000000000003

Answer (score 2):

I used `(num-0.05).toFixed(1)` to get the second decimal floored.

Answer (score 2):

It's more reliable to get two floating points without rounding.

[**Reference Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833137/how-to-make-number-format-not-to-round-numbers-up)

```js
var number = 10.5859;
var fixed2FloatPoints = parseInt(number * 100) / 100;
console.log(fixed2FloatPoints);
```

Thank You !

Answer (score 2):

My solution in typescript (can easily be ported to JS):

```
/**
 * Returns the price with correct precision as a string
 *
 * @param   price The price in decimal to be formatted.
 * @param   decimalPlaces The number of decimal places to use
 * @return  string The price in Decimal formatting.
 */
type toDecimal = (price: number, decimalPlaces?: number) => string;
const toDecimalOdds: toDecimal = (
  price: number,
  decimalPlaces: number = 2,
): string => {
  const priceString: string = price.toString();
  const pointIndex: number = priceString.indexOf('.');

  // Return the integer part if decimalPlaces is 0
  if (decimalPlaces === 0) {
    return priceString.substr(0, pointIndex);
  }

  // Return value with 0s appended after decimal if the price is an integer
  if (pointIndex === -1) {
    const padZeroString: string = '0'.repeat(decimalPlaces);

    return `${priceString}.${padZeroString}`;
  }

  // If numbers after decimal are less than decimalPlaces, append with 0s
  const padZeroLen: number = priceString.length - pointIndex - 1;
  if (padZeroLen > 0 && padZeroLen < decimalPlaces) {
    const padZeroString: string = '0'.repeat(padZeroLen);

    return `${priceString}${padZeroString}`;
  }

  return priceString.substr(0, pointIndex + decimalPlaces + 1);
};
```

Test cases:

```
  expect(filters.toDecimalOdds(3.14159)).toBe('3.14');
  expect(filters.toDecimalOdds(3.14159, 2)).toBe('3.14');
  expect(filters.toDecimalOdds(3.14159, 0)).toBe('3');
  expect(filters.toDecimalOdds(3.14159, 10)).toBe('3.1415900000');
  expect(filters.toDecimalOdds(8.2)).toBe('8.20');
```

Any improvements?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, that **truncates** and **round**:

```
function round (number, decimals, truncate) {
    if (truncate) {
        number = number.toFixed(decimals + 1);
        return parseFloat(number.slice(0, -1));
    }

    var n = Math.pow(10.0, decimals);
    return Math.round(number * n) / n;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Roll your own `toFixed` function: for positive values `Math.floor` works fine.

```
function toFixed(num, fixed) {
    fixed = fixed || 0;
    fixed = Math.pow(10, fixed);
    return Math.floor(num * fixed) / fixed;
}
```

For negative values `Math.floor` is round of the values. So you can use `Math.ceil` instead.

Example,

```
Math.ceil(-15.778665 * 10000) / 10000 = -15.7786
Math.floor(-15.778665 * 10000) / 10000 = -15.7787 // wrong.
```

Comment: So many of these answers have a multiplication inside a Math.floor() function. This will fail for some numbers! Floating point arithmetic is not accurate and you need to use different methods.

Answer (score 1):

Gumbo's second solution, with the regular expression, does work but is slow because of the regular expression.  Gumbo's first solution fails in certain situations due to imprecision in floating points numbers.  See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sQXdE/16/) for a demonstration and a benchmark.  The second solution takes about 1636 nanoseconds per call on my current system, Intel Core i5-2500 CPU at 3.30 GHz.

The solution I've written involves adding a small compensation to take care of floating point imprecision.  It is basically instantaneous, i.e. on the order of nanoseconds.  I clocked 2 nanoseconds per call but the JavaScript timers are not very precise or granular.  Here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sQXdE/17/) and the code.

```
function toFixedWithoutRounding (value, precision)
{
    var factorError = Math.pow(10, 14);
    var factorTruncate = Math.pow(10, 14 - precision);
    var factorDecimal = Math.pow(10, precision);
    return Math.floor(Math.floor(value * factorError + 1) / factorTruncate) / factorDecimal;
}

var values = [1.1299999999, 1.13, 1.139999999, 1.14, 1.14000000001, 1.13 * 100];

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
{
    var value = values[i];
    console.log(value + " --> " + toFixedWithoutRounding(value, 2));
}

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
{
    var value = values[i];
    console.log(value + " --> " + toFixedWithoutRounding(value, 4));
}

console.log("type of result is " + typeof toFixedWithoutRounding(1.13 * 100 / 100, 2));

// Benchmark
var value = 1.13 * 100;
var startTime = new Date();
var numRun = 1000000;
var nanosecondsPerMilliseconds = 1000000;

for (var run = 0; run < numRun; run++)
    toFixedWithoutRounding(value, 2);

var endTime = new Date();
var timeDiffNs = nanosecondsPerMilliseconds * (endTime - startTime);
var timePerCallNs = timeDiffNs / numRun;
console.log("Time per call (nanoseconds): " + timePerCallNs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Already there are some suitable answer with regular expression and arithmetic calculation, you can also try this

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = 12.234556; 
    str = str.toString().split('.');
    var res = str[1].slice(0, 2);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str[0]+'.'+res;
}

// output: 12.23
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on **David D's** answer:

```
function NumberFormat(num,n) {
  var num = (arguments[0] != null) ? arguments[0] : 0;
  var n = (arguments[1] != null) ? arguments[1] : 2;
  if(num > 0){
    num = String(num);
    if(num.indexOf('.') !== -1) {
      var numarr = num.split(".");
      if (numarr.length > 1) {
        if(n > 0){
          var temp = numarr[0] + ".";
          for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(i < numarr[1].length){
              temp += numarr[1].charAt(i);
            }
          }
          num = Number(temp);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return Number(num);
}

console.log('NumberFormat(123.85,2)',NumberFormat(123.85,2));
console.log('NumberFormat(123.851,2)',NumberFormat(123.851,2));
console.log('NumberFormat(0.85,2)',NumberFormat(0.85,2));
console.log('NumberFormat(0.851,2)',NumberFormat(0.851,2));
console.log('NumberFormat(0.85156,2)',NumberFormat(0.85156,2));
console.log('NumberFormat(0.85156,4)',NumberFormat(0.85156,4));
console.log('NumberFormat(0.85156,8)',NumberFormat(0.85156,8));
console.log('NumberFormat(".85156",2)',NumberFormat(".85156",2));
console.log('NumberFormat("0.85156",2)',NumberFormat("0.85156",2));
console.log('NumberFormat("1005.85156",2)',NumberFormat("1005.85156",2));
console.log('NumberFormat("0",2)',NumberFormat("0",2));
console.log('NumberFormat("",2)',NumberFormat("",2));
console.log('NumberFormat(85156,8)',NumberFormat(85156,8));
console.log('NumberFormat("85156",2)',NumberFormat("85156",2));
console.log('NumberFormat("85156.",2)',NumberFormat("85156.",2));

// NumberFormat(123.85,2) 123.85
// NumberFormat(123.851,2) 123.85
// NumberFormat(0.85,2) 0.85
// NumberFormat(0.851,2) 0.85
// NumberFormat(0.85156,2) 0.85
// NumberFormat(0.85156,4) 0.8515
// NumberFormat(0.85156,8) 0.85156
// NumberFormat(".85156",2) 0.85
// NumberFormat("0.85156",2) 0.85
// NumberFormat("1005.85156",2) 1005.85
// NumberFormat("0",2) 0
// NumberFormat("",2) 0
// NumberFormat(85156,8) 85156
// NumberFormat("85156",2) 85156
// NumberFormat("85156.",2) 85156
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is did it with string

```
export function withoutRange(number) {
  const str = String(number);
  const dotPosition = str.indexOf('.');
  if (dotPosition > 0) {
    const length = str.substring().length;
    const end = length > 3 ? 3 : length;
    return str.substring(0, dotPosition + end);
  }
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All these answers seem a bit complicated. I would just subtract 0.5 from your number and use toFixed().

Comment: You meant 0.005?

Answer (score 1):

Taking the knowledge from all the previous answers combined,

this is what I came up with as a solution:

```
function toFixedWithoutRounding(num, fractionDigits) {
  if ((num > 0 && num < 0.000001) || (num < 0 && num > -0.000001)) {
    // HACK: below this js starts to turn numbers into exponential form like 1e-7.
    // This gives wrong results so we are just changing the original number to 0 here
    // as we don't need such small numbers anyway.
    num = 0;
  }
  const re = new RegExp('^-?\\d+(?:\.\\d{0,' + (fractionDigits || -1) + '})?');
  return Number(num.toString().match(re)[0]).toFixed(fractionDigits);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function toFixed(num, fixed) {
    fixed = fixed || 0;
    var front = Math.floor(num);
    var back = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= fixed; i++) {
        var value = Math.floor(num * Math.pow(10, i)) % 10;
        back += value / Math.pow(10, i);
    }
    return front + back;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED JUNE 2021**

this will fix any number with the given length without rounding

```js
let FixWithoutRounding = (v, l) => {
      const intPart = Math.trunc(v).toString()
      const fractionPart = v.toString().slice(v.toString().indexOf('.') + 1)
      if (fractionPart.length > l) {
        return Number(intPart.concat('.', fractionPart.slice(0, l)))
      } else {
        const padded = intPart.concat('.', fractionPart.padEnd(l, '0'))
        return padded
      }
    }

console.log(FixWithoutRounding(123.123, 12))
```

Comment: this does not work with negative numbers

Answer (score 1):

In order to collaborate, there is a solution that I had to use with Bitcoin math operations. The point is that Bitcoin uses 8 decimal numbers, and we needed no round.

So, I did this:

- do the calculation
- take the value and set 9 decimal houses

  `value = value.toFixed(9);`
- take the substring cutting off the last decimal number:

  `value = value.substring(0, value.length - 1);`

No. This is not elegant, but it's a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, and decided using string manipulation in TS.

If not enough decimals, it will return the original value

```
const getDecimalsWithoutRounding = (value: number, numberOfDecimals: number) => {
  const stringValue: string = value?.toString();
  const dotIdx: number = stringValue?.indexOf('.');
  if (dotIdx) {
    return parseFloat(stringValue.slice(0, dotIdx + numberOfDecimals + 1));
  } else {
    return value;
  }
};

console.log(getDecimalsWithoutRounding(3.34589, 2)); /// 3.34
console.log(getDecimalsWithoutRounding(null, 2));  ///null
console.log(getDecimalsWithoutRounding(55.123456789, 5)); /// 55.12345
console.log(getDecimalsWithoutRounding(10, 2));  /// 10
console.log(getDecimalsWithoutRounding(10.6, 5)); /// 10.6
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient solution (for 2 fraction digits) is to subtract 0.005 before calling `toFixed()`

```
function toFixed2( num ) { return (num-0.005).toFixed(2) }
```

Negative numbers will be rounded down too (away from zero). The OP didn't tell anything about negative numbers.

Comment: It works. The issue here is, that `4.27` does not exists and is rounded to `4.26999999999999957`. And rounding down this number is `4.26`. Try `(4.27).toPrecision(18)` to verify.

Comment: In general, most numbers has no exact representation as computer number (IEEE 754). So every input is rounded to the nearest possible value first. And here 0.005 is also rounded to a value slightly larger than 0.005. And so each calculation step make a floating point number more inexact.

Answer (score 0):

I know there are already few working examples, but I  think it's worth to propose my String.toFixed equivalent, some may find it helpful.

That's my toFixed alternative, that don't round numbers, just truncates it or adds zeroes according to given precision. For extra long number it uses JS build-in rounding when precision is to long.
Function works for all problematic number I've found on stack.

```
function toFixedFixed(value, precision = 0) {
    let stringValue = isNaN(+value) ? '0' : String(+value);

    if (stringValue.indexOf('e') > -1 || stringValue === 'Infinity' || stringValue === '-Infinity') {
        throw new Error('To large number to be processed');
    }

    let [ beforePoint, afterPoint ] = stringValue.indexOf('.') > -1 ? stringValue.split('.') : [ stringValue, ''];

    // Force automatic rounding for some long real numbers that ends with 99X, by converting it to string, cutting off last digit, then adding extra nines and casting it on number again
    // e.g. 2.0199999999999996: +('2.019999999999999' + '9999') will give 2.02
    if (stringValue.length >= 17 && afterPoint.length > 2 && +afterPoint.substr(afterPoint.length - 3) > 995) {
        stringValue = String(+(stringValue.substr(0, afterPoint.length - 1) + '9'.repeat(stringValue.split('.').shift().length + 4)));
        [ beforePoint, afterPoint ] = String(stringValue).indexOf('.') > -1 ? stringValue.split('.') : [ stringValue, ''];
    }

    if (precision === 0) {
        return beforePoint;
    } else if (afterPoint.length > precision) {
        return `${beforePoint}.${afterPoint.substr(0, precision)}`;
    } else {
        return `${beforePoint}.${afterPoint}${'0'.repeat(precision - afterPoint.length)}`;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that precision may not be handled properly for numbers of length 18 and greater, e.g. 64-bit Chrome will round it or add "e+" / "e-" to keep number's length at 18.

If you want to perform operations on real numbers it's safer to multiply it by `Math.sqrt(10, precision)` first, make the calculations, then dive result by multiplier's value.

Example:

> `0.06 + 0.01` is `0.06999999999999999`, and every formatting function
>   that's not rounding will truncate it to `0.06` for precision `2`.
>
> But if you'll perform same operation with multiplier&divider: `(0.06 * 100 + 0.01 * 100) / 100`, you'll get `0.07`.

That's why it's so important to use such multiplier/divider when dealing with real numbers in javascript, especially when you're calculating money...

Answer (score 0):

```
function FixWithoutRounding(number, digits) {
  var gbZero = '0000000000';
  var subNumber = number.toString().split('.');

  if (subNumber.length === 1)
    return [subNumber[0], '.', '0000'].join('');

  var result = '';
  if (subNumber[1].length > digits) {
    result = subNumber[1].substring(0, digits);
  } else {
    result = subNumber[1] + gbZero.substring(0, digits - subNumber[1].length);
  }

  return [subNumber[0], '.', result].join('');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Correct 2024 way

Use [Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```
var num = parseFloat( 15.7784514 );
var truncated = num.toLocaleString( 'en-US', {
   minimumFractionDigits: 2,
   maximumFractionDigits: 2,
   roundingMode: "trunc"
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [bignumber.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/) you could go with this one-line solution

```
BigNumber(15.7784514).multipliedBy(100).integerValue(BigNumber.ROUND_DOWN).dividedBy(100).toFixed();
// 15.77
```

```js
console.log(15.7784514, '->', BigNumber(15.7784514).multipliedBy(100).integerValue(BigNumber.ROUND_DOWN).dividedBy(100).toFixed());
console.log(4.27, '->', BigNumber(4.27).multipliedBy(100).integerValue(BigNumber.ROUND_DOWN).dividedBy(100).toFixed());
console.log(0.001, '->', BigNumber(0.001).multipliedBy(100).integerValue(BigNumber.ROUND_DOWN).dividedBy(100).toFixed());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bignumber.js/9.1.2/bignumber.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is another one variant to save .toFixed([digits]) functional without rounding float variable:

```
Number.prototype.toRealFixed = function(digits) {
    return Math.floor(this.valueOf() * Math.pow(10, digits)) / Math.pow(10, digits);
};
```

And calling:

```
var float_var = 0.02209062;
float_var.toRealFixed();
```

Comment: Fails using 4.27

Answer (score -1):

`const toFixed = (value) => value.toString().slice(0,5);`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value

Answer (score -2):

Thanks **Martin Varmus**

```
function floorFigure(figure, decimals){
     if (!decimals) decimals = 2;
     const pow = 10 ** decimals
     return Math.trunc(figure * pow) / pow;
};

floorFigure(123.5999)    =>   "123.59"
floorFigure(123.5999, 3) =>   "123.599"
```

I made a simple update and I got proper rounding. The update is following line

```
return ((figure*d)/d).toFixed(decimals);
```

remove parseInt() function

Comment: Tweaks to another another answer tend to do better as comments, especially because the OP was looking for answers with no rounding.

Comment: When I run your function, I get `floorFigure(123.5999) => "123.60"` and `floorFigure(123.5999, 3) => "123.600"`.  Care to clarify?

Comment: @BradKoch the one with parseInt is proper, this is invalid.

Answer (score -2):

a simple solution

```
const toFixedNoRounding = (value, digits) => {
  const factor = Math.pow(10, digits);

  return Math.trunc(value * factor) / factor;
};
```