# Limit the amount of number shown after a decimal place in javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, decimal, limit

Hay, i have some floats like these

```
4.3455
2.768
3.67
```

and i want to display them like this

```
4.34
2.76
3.67
```

I don't want to round the number up or down, just limit the amount of numbers shown after the decimal place to 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript -  display two decimal places, no rounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/javascript-display-two-decimal-places-no-rounding)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You're looking for [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
var x = 4.3455;
alert(x.toFixed(2)); // alerts 4.35 -- not what you wanted!
```

...but it looks like you want to truncate rather than rounding, so:

```
var x = 4.3455;
x = Math.floor(x * 100) / 100;
alert(x.toFixed(2)); // alerts 4.34
```

Comment: You are right, i was using toFixed() but i was also using parseInt which was converting my float to a number and toFixed() was always returning xx.00 !

Comment: You were right about the dupe.  When I read that it clicked in my head that I saw it too, a day or so ago :-)

Comment: @dotty: Ah, yes, `parseInt` will convert the number to a string, then convert that string back into a number disregarding anything after the decimal. :-) But no need for it in this case, you can call functions on numbers (they automagically get converted from primitives into `Number` instances).

Comment: @Andy E: And yet I can't find it. I gave up, if it's that hard to find, we need a duplicate! :-) (Edit: Ah, you found it. I guess it's just so new that Google hasn't indexed it yet.)

Comment: @TJC: yeah, actually 8 days ago... the concept of time is just lost on me these days!

Answer (score 36):

As T.J answered, the `toFixed` method will do the appropriate rounding if necessary. It will also add trailing zeroes, which is not always ideal.

```
(4.55555).toFixed(2);
//-> "4.56"

(4).toFixed(2);
//-> "4.00"
```

If you cast the return value to a number, those trailing zeroes will be dropped. This is a simpler approach than doing your own rounding or truncation math.

```
+parseFloat((4.55555).toFixed(2));
//-> 4.56

+parseFloat((4).toFixed(2));
//-> 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the casting to number idea!

Comment: The casting idea is brilliant 

Comment: Sweet answer — simple, effective, and not particularly obvious. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Good news everyone! Since a while there is an alternative: [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

While it isn't exactly made for rounding, there is some usefuls options arguments.

**minimumIntegerDigits**

> The minimum number of integer digits to use. Possible values are from 1 > to 21; the default is 1.

**minimumFractionDigits**

> The minimum number of fraction digits to use.
>
> Possible values are from 0 > to 20; the default for plain number and percent formatting is 0; t
>
> The default for currency formatting is the number of minor unit
> digits provided by the ISO 4217 currency code list (2 if the list
> doesn't provide that information).

**maximumFractionDigits**

> The maximum number of fraction digits to use.
>
> Possible values are from 0 > to 20; the default for plain number formatting is the larger of minimumFractionDigits and 3
>
> The default for currency formatting is the larger of minimumFractionDigits and the number of minor unit
> digits provided by the ISO 4217 currency code list (2 if the list
> doesn't provide that information); the default for percent formatting
> is the larger of minimumFractionDigits and 0.

**minimumSignificantDigits**

> The minimum number of significant digits to use. Possible values are from 1 to 21; the default is 1.

**maximumSignificantDigits**

> The maximum number of significant digits to use. Possible values are from 1 to 21; the default is 21.

**Example usage:**

```js
var bigNum = 8884858284485 * 4542825114616565
var smallNum = 88885 / 4545114616565

console.log(bigNum) // Output scientific

console.log(smallNum) // Output scientific

// String
console.log(
  bigNum.toLocaleString('fullwide', {useGrouping:false})
) 

// Return a string, rounded at 12 decimals
console.log(
  smallNum.toLocaleString('fullwide', {maximumFractionDigits:12})
)


// Return a string, rounded at 8 decimals
console.log(
  smallNum.toLocaleString('fullwide', {minimumFractionDigits:8, maximumFractionDigits:8})
)

// Return an Integer, rounded as need, js will convert it back to scientific!
console.log(
  +smallNum.toLocaleString('fullwide', {maximumFractionDigits:12})
)

// Return same Integer, don't use parseInt for precision!
console.log(
  parseInt(smallNum.toLocaleString('fullwide', {maximumFractionDigits:12}))
)
```

**But** this does not match the question, it is rounding:

```js
function cutDecimals(number,decimals){
  return number.toLocaleString('fullwide', {maximumFractionDigits:decimals})
}

console.log(
  cutDecimals(4.3455,2),
  cutDecimals(2.768,2),
  cutDecimals(3.67,2)
)
```

​​​​​​

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want rounding to 2 decimal places, use `toFixed()` to round to *n* decimal places and chop all those off but 2:

```
var num = 4.3455.toFixed(20);
alert(num.slice(0, -18));
//-> 4.34
```

Note that this does have the slight downside of rounding when the number of decimal places passed to `toFixed()` is less than the number of decimal places of the actual number passed in and those decimal places are large numbers.  For instance `(4.99999999999).toFixed(10)` will give you `5.0000000000`.  However, this isn't a problem if you can ensure the number of decimal places will be lower than that passed to `toFixed()`.  It does, however, make @TJ's solution a bit more robust.

Answer (score 6):

**Warning!** The currently accepted solution fails in some cases, e.g. with 4.27 it wrongly returns 4.26.

Here is a [general solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/display-two-decimal-places-no-rounding/46171960#46171960) that works always.

(Maybe I should put this as a comment, but at the time of this writing, I don't have the required reputation)

Answer (score 1):

Use toPrecision :)

```
var y = 67537653.76828732668326;
y = (String(y).indexOf('.') !== -1) ? +y.toPrecision(String(y).indexOf('.') + 2) : +y.toFixed(2);
// => 67537653.76
```

The 2 in the second line dictates the number of decimal places, this approach returns a number, if you want a string remove the "+" operator.