# How to limit the length of a variable in js

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I made a function in js which calculates the average of 5 numbers and stores it in a variable.
for example, if i have the variable 
var avg =  (0.18 + 0.18 + 0.19 + 0.21 + 1.14)/5;
It gives me this answer : 0.37999999999999995.
 I need the length of the answer to be only 3 or 4. Please help me resolve this problem. Thank You!

Comment: `toFixed()` can be used to specify how many numbers after the decimal point should be displayed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit the amount of number shown after a decimal place in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256030/limit-the-amount-of-number-shown-after-a-decimal-place-in-javascript)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**EDIT: You can also use [.toFixed(n)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) see Answer below**

Greetings,...

Comment: Because otherwise the avg isn't used as STRING and the substring Method don't work.

Comment: Yea.. forgot toFixed(n)

Comment: How fair is that? A totally wrong answer, totally changed (by grabbing someone else's answer) and was accepted.

Comment: So i upvoted Jameys answer. For Kdvinmk's "correct answer" I can't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

```
var avg = (0.18 + 0.18 + 0.19 + 0.21 + 1.14)/5;
avg.toFixed(3);
```

limits the length to only show 3 numbers after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want to do

To limit the total length with **[toPrecision(n)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toprecision.asp)**:

```
var num = new Number(14.12);
console.log(num.toPrecision(2));//outputs 14
console.log(num.toPrecision(3));//outputs 14.1
console.log(num.toPrecision(4));//outputs 14.12
console.log(num.toPrecision(5));//outputs 14.120
```

To limit the decimal part, use **[toFixed(n)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)** :

```
parseFloat(Math.round(num * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

The input 1.346 will return 1.35

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
parseFloat(avg.toFixed(3));


    var avg = (0.18 + 0.18 + 0.19 + 0.21 + 1.14)/5;
    avg = parseFloat(avg.toFixed(3));
    alert(avg);
```