# How to short length number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

when I calc this value I got a big number like 48.4979898749,

how convert this to 48.49 ???

Comment: Oops, marked dups appear wrong.   so -> `Math.trunc(48.4979898749 * 100) / 100`

Comment: Thanks Keith, this helped me, `"48.4979898749.toFixed(2)"`

Comment: The accepted answer here shows how to get a truncated number or get a rounded number: [Limit the amount of number shown after a decimal place in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256030/limit-the-amount-of-number-shown-after-a-decimal-place-in-javascript). I think the correct duplicate should be this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the number and apply [`Number#toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) with the wanted number of digits.

```js
var valuee = document.getElementById("valueNum"),
    result = document.getElementById("res");        

valuee.onkeyup = function () {
    "use strict";
    result.innerHTML = "المبلغ المطلوب " + (valuee.value * 0.0680).toFixed(2) + " دولار";
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="valueNum">
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: `48.4979898749.toFixed(2)` is '48.50',..

Comment: technically, toFixed(2) converts 48.4979898749 to 48.50, not 48.49 ... but I think the OP wasn't thinking about rounding

Comment: The accepted answer here shows how to get a truncated number or get a rounded number: [Limit the amount of number shown after a decimal place in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256030/limit-the-amount-of-number-shown-after-a-decimal-place-in-javascript). I think the correct duplicate should be this question.

Comment: in the duplicates, there is always a funky converting to number, either by parsing or with `Number`. this answer uses an implicit casting with a number expecting operand.