# Javascript auto calculating with (+) and (-)

Tags: javascript, math

I need some help finding the error in my javascript calculation.

I need to calculate the sum of my input boxes automatically and have my user be able to edit the calculation using + or - buttons.

The code I have already does the calculation automatically if you manually enter the numbers, but pressing the + or - does not change the calculation.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function Calc(className){
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
var total = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i){
total += parseInt(elements[i].value);
}

document.form0.total.value = total;
}

function addone(field) {
field.value = Number(field.value) + 1;
}

function subtractone(field) {
field.value = Number(field.value) - 1;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="form0" id="form0">

1: <input type="text" name="box1" id="box1" class="add" value="0" onKeyUp="Calc('add')" onChange="updatesum()" onClick="this.focus();this.select();" />
<input type="button" value=" + " onclick="addone(box1);">
<input type="button" value=" - " onclick="subtractone(box1);">
<br />

2: <input type="text" name="box2" id="box2" class="add" value="0" onKeyUp="Calc('add')" onClick="this.focus();this.select();" />
<input type="button" value=" + " onclick="addone(box2);">
<input type="button" value=" - " onclick="subtractone(box2);">
<br />

3: <input type="text" name="box3" id="box3" class="add" value="0" onKeyUp="Calc('add')" onClick="this.focus();this.select();" />
<input type="button" value=" + " onclick="addone(box3);">
<input type="button" value=" - " onclick="subtractone(box3);">
<br />

<br />
Total: <input readonly style="border:0px; font-size:14; color:red;" id="total" name="total">

</form>
</body></html>
```

Im sure the issue must be small, I just cant put my finger on it.

Comment: You also have `onChange="updatesum()` which seems like a mistake - `updatesum` isn't defined here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way is to update the sum when you click the buttons. You can add `Calc('add')` to the `onclick` event, or to the `addone` and `subtractone` functions (You probably want to add the class as a parameter though). For example:

```
function addone(field) {
  field.value = Number(field.value) + 1;
  Calc('add');
}

function subtractone(field) {
  field.value = Number(field.value) - 1;
  Calc('add');
}
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/umimu4/

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function `Calc('add')` after the `addone()` and call `subtractone()` call.

EX:

```
<input type="button" value=" + " onclick="addone(box1); Calc('add')">
<input type="button" value=" - " onclick="subtractone(box1); Calc('add')">
```

The `updatesum()` method also seems to be missing.

I think [@Kobi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573480/javascript-auto-calculating-with-and/4573510#4573500) has a better answer.

Comment: any ideas why the total isnt showing decimals? For example, adding 5.5 to a field only shows in the total as 5

Comment: Because You are using `parseInt()` instead use `parseFloat()` in your `Calc()` method.

Comment: It can leads to problems with decimal places, any calculation involving floating points will not give correct values, you may have to round off the values to some decimal places.  Ex: `5.5 + 5.2 + 2.2` will give you `12.89999999999` instead of `12.9`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/javascript-display-two-decimal-places-no-rounding may help in in this.

Answer (score 0):

Is it wat you need?
I changed your own code:

```
&lt;html&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
&lt;script language=&quot;javascript&quot;&gt;
function Calc(className){
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
var total = 0;

for(var i = 0; i &lt; elements.length; ++i){
total += parseInt(elements[i].value);
}

document.form0.total.value = total;
}

function addone(field) {
field.value = Number(field.value) + 1;
}

function subtractone(field) {
field.value = Number(field.value) - 1;
}
&lt;/script&gt;

&lt;/head&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
&lt;form name=&quot;form0&quot; id=&quot;form0&quot;&gt;

1: &lt;input type=&quot;text&quot; name=&quot;box1&quot; id=&quot;box1&quot; class=&quot;add&quot; value=&quot;0&quot; onKeyUp=&quot;Calc(&#039;add&#039;)&quot; onChange=&quot;updatesum()&quot; onClick=&quot;this.focus();this.select();&quot; /&gt;
&lt;input type=&quot;button&quot; value=&quot; + &quot; onclick=&quot;addone(box1); Calc(&#039;add&#039;)&quot;&gt;
&lt;input type=&quot;button&quot; value=&quot; - &quot; onclick=&quot;subtractone(box1); Calc(&#039;add&#039;)&quot;&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;

2: &lt;input type=&quot;text&quot; name=&quot;box2&quot; id=&quot;box2&quot; class=&quot;add&quot; value=&quot;0&quot; onKeyUp=&quot;Calc(&#039;add&#039;)&quot; onClick=&quot;this.focus();this.select();&quot; /&gt;
&lt;input type=&quot;button&quot; value=&quot; + &quot; onclick=&quot;addone(box2); Calc(&#039;add&#039;)&quot;&gt;
&lt;input type=&quot;button&quot; value=&quot; - &quot; onclick=&quot;subtractone(box2); Calc(&#039;add&#039;)&quot;&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;

3: &lt;input type=&quot;text&quot; name=&quot;box3&quot; id=&quot;box3&quot; class=&quot;add&quot; value=&quot;0&quot; onKeyUp=&quot;Calc(&#039;add&#039;)&quot; onClick=&quot;this.focus();this.select();&quot; /&gt;
&lt;input type=&quot;button&quot; value=&quot; + &quot; onclick=&quot;addone(box3); Calc(&#039;add&#039;)&quot;&gt;
&lt;input type=&quot;button&quot; value=&quot; - &quot; onclick=&quot;subtractone(box3); Calc(&#039;add&#039;)&quot;&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;

&lt;br /&gt;
Total: &lt;input readonly style=&quot;border:0px; font-size:14; color:red;&quot; id=&quot;total&quot; name=&quot;total&quot;&gt;

&lt;/form&gt;
&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;
```

Comment: The attribute `language="javascript"` is not a standard, it is better to use `type="text/javascript"` even though the standard is `type="application/javascript"` since IE will not understand this.

Comment: I know, you are right but I edited the original script! It is not my own one.