# How to format a float number without rounding?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to format a float number (lets say 341.75) by setting the decimal point to "1". I tried:

```
var num = 341.75;
alert(num.toFixed(1)); // output: 341.8
alert(num.toPrecision(1)); // output: 341.8
```

but what I need is 341.7 ! apparently both methods try to round it, is there a way to do that without rounding ?

Comment: To format a float without rounding, you'd have to print it in it's binary form. You're converting it to a decimal representation, there will be discrepancies along the way.

Comment: Check out this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/javascript-display-two-decimal-places-no-rounding][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/javascript-display-two-decimal-places-no-rounding

Comment: `num.toStr()` to convert to a string, then substring operations to extract the chunks you want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about little cheating?

```
Math.floor(num * 10) / 10
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev what about `49.1234567890123456` with call `toString()`? Can it be also handled somehow, so that there would be no rounding?

Comment: @Eugene: what do you mean? There's no rounding.

Answer (score 6):

You could subtract 0.05 before formatting.

Comment: This one is the least involved. +1

Comment: It stops being least involved when you make it work for all numbers.

Comment: Seems to fail if you have `341.5`. The result I get is `341.4` for some reason.

Comment: This is the standard way to do it on programming langueses that do not support rounding down. You might want to wrap it in a function with arbitrary cuttoff point.

Comment: @am That is very strange. As Javascript uses asymetric positive infinity rounding you should get 341.5. This behaviour can happen in programming languages that use banker's rounding by default. It might be due to small floating point errors.

Comment: OK, here's the general version:  you could subtract 0.5 / Math.pow(10, p) where p is the precision that you are passing to toFixed().

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `substring()` method after having converted your number to a String:

```
num = num.substring(0, num.indexOf(".") + 2));
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.  But it is a little "hacky"... but it definitely works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any other suitable method (atleast on the [MDN reference for Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number))

So maybe you could go the *hackish* route:

```
var num = 341.75;  //341; //try without decimal
var str = num.toString();
var len = str.indexOf(".")==-1 ? str.length : str.indexOf(".")+2;
alert(str.substring(0,len));
```

See it in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/giddygeek/YtTzL/3/

Comment: yep, +1'd it, now that's good thinking! While typing out my question (there weren't any answers) by the time I saved the fiddle and posted, I figured they'd be some smarter answers! =S

Comment: To whoever downvoted, not sure why, it may be a hacky solution, but it does work!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you'd have an issue if there's no `.` in the original number. `.indexOf()` will return `-1` in that case, so you'll end up with `str.substring(0,1)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   You can try this if you
```

```js
function myFunction() {
            var str = 12.234556; 
            str = str.toString().split('.');
            var res = str[1].slice(0, 2);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str[0]+'.'+res;
        }
        
       myFunction();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></>
```

want to round