# How to restrict input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have input where user must enter the number of the with no more than 4 decimal places:

```
<input type="text" name="price" />
```

how to do that, so it is impossible to enter more than 4 digits after the decimal point?

Comment: may be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570722/restrict-input-field-to-two-decimals-with-jquery

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: If you are using PHP, validate after POST takes place

Answer (score 0):

There is a method for that too,

```
.toFixed(4); // 4 would be the number of ints after decimal point.
```

It would get/allow only 4 characters after the `.` character.

> The toFixed() method formats a number using fixed-point notation.

Further more you can learn some more from the Document I have attached to the post. They have a well explained Example of this method too.

From Mozilla Developer Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5:

```
<input type="number" step="0.0001" />
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2h4TC/)

If you want to style invalid inputs (some browsers do it by default), you can use `:invalid` selector:

```
input:invalid {   box-shadow: 0 0 1.5px 1px red;   }
```

Note this approach won't attempt to truncate the number automagically, but if the user enters more than four decimal digits, the input will become invalid, and thus the form won't be submitted:

[image: Screenshot on Firefox]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Why do so many people think that this doesn't answer the question? Please clarify :S

Comment: the question is dumb, and your answer is not exact. It does not check for number of digits. It only sets stepping.

Comment: @madhead OP wants to restrict number of digits after decimal point. Setting step of 0.0001 will make the input invalid if the number has more than 4 decimal digits. It won't modify the number attempting to "fix" it, if that's what you mean.

Comment: try it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/sv9hX/ it only affects `stepping`: http://screencast.com/t/JtuHMPWldt

Comment: @madhead Yes, but if a form contains an invalid input, the form won't be submitted: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2h4TC), [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/u7nWm.gif). I have edited my answer, I hope now it's more clear.

Comment: On my Linux Mint with Chrome v35 the form is not validated: http://screencloud.net/v/p4TZ

Comment: @madhead Because the restriction doesn't affect all digits, only decimal ones, like OP said: "no more than 4 decimal places"

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#price").on('keyup',function(){
    $("#price").val($("#price").val().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''));
    var price = parseFloat($("#price").val());
    var decimals = ((price).toFixed(5)).replace(/^-?\d*\.?|0+$/g, '').length;
    if(decimals >= 4)
    {
       $("#price").val(price.toFixed(4));
    }
});
```

Determines the number of decimals, if it's greater than 4 it sets the value in the input back to 4.

Also doesn't allow any non-numeric characters in the input.

Error pop ups are crap UI.  http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/z4f5B/3/

Answer (score 0):

User toFixed:

```
<input type="text" name="price" onBlur="this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(4);" />
```

Answer (score -2):

Add maxlength="4" to your input code.

```
<input type="text" name="price" maxlength="4" />
```

Comment: maxlength will invalidate 12345, 12.345 and possibly even 123.4, depending on how the period is interpreted.