# Javascript toFixed function

Tags: javascript, tofixed

**The expected result of:**

```
(1.175).toFixed(2) = 1.18 and
(5.175).toFixed(2) = 5.18
```

**But in JS showing:**

```
(1.175).toFixed(2) = 1.18 but 
*(5.175).toFixed(2) = 5.17*
```

How to rectify the problem?

Comment: Why is it a problem ?

Comment: I don't know if this resolve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808671/javascript-how-to-prevent-tofixed-from-rounding-off-decimal-numbers

Comment: What is the expected result of (5.175).toFixed(2)

Comment: possible duplicate? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977796/why-does-math-round2-5-return-2-instead-of-3-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977796/why-does-math-round2-5-return-2-instead-of-3-in-c)

Comment: What a waste of time having a function behave like that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could always try using round, instead of toFixed.

`Math.round(5.175*100)/100`

You could even try putting it in some prototype method if you want.

Created a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/EPulUzaW/1/) that implements a simple prototype on Number.

```
Number.prototype.toFixed = function(decimals) {
 return Math.round(this * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / (Math.pow(10, decimals)); 
};
```

Comment: I like this solution, except you are defeating the purpose of the function, which is to ensure a specific amount of digits after decimals. Your function failed with numbers like, 1, 1.0, 1.00000, etc. You can solve this by just adding the "toFixed()" to your return statement like: "return (Math.round(this * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / (Math.pow(10, decimals))).toFixed(decimals);"

Comment: I like your comment, since I was dealing with the same issue when I was using this solution.  The problem with your approach though is that you can't use the function you're redefining in the definition of that function.  It goes into recursive lala land.  My solution here https://jsfiddle.net/yxjd78sj/ captures the old .toFixed() function definition and uses it as .oldToFixed() instead.  Let me know what you think!

Answer (score 11):

It's not a bug. It's related to the fact numbers aren't stored in decimal but in [IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) (so `5.175` isn't *exactly* stored).

If you want to round in a specific direction (up) and you consistently have numbers of this precision, you might use this trick :

```
(5.175 + 0.00001).toFixed(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because the numbers are stored as [IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

I would recommend you to use the Math class (round, floor or ceil methods, depending on your needing).

I've just created a class MathHelper that can easily solve your problem:

```
var MathHelper = (function () {
    this.round = function (number, numberOfDecimals) {
        var aux = Math.pow(10, numberOfDecimals);
        return Math.round(number * aux) / aux;
    };
    this.floor = function (number, numberOfDecimals) {
        var aux = Math.pow(10, numberOfDecimals);
        return Math.floor(number * aux) / aux;
    };
    this.ceil = function (number, numberOfDecimals) {
        var aux = Math.pow(10, numberOfDecimals);
        return Math.ceil(number * aux) / aux;
    };

    return {
        round: round,
        floor: floor,
        ceil: ceil
    }
})();
```

Usage:

```
MathHelper.round(5.175, 2)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v2Dj7/

Comment: Doesn't solve the general problem of floating point inaccuracies: `MathHelper.round(1.005, 2)` returns `1` when it is expected to return `1.01`. As does `(1.005).toFixed(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think this *is* a bug in the implementation of `Number.prototype.toFixed`. The algorithm given in **[ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) 20.1.3.3 10-a** says to round up as a tie-breaker. As others have mentioned, there probably isn't a tie to break due to floating point imprecisions in the implementation. But that doesn't make it right :)

At least this behavior is consistent across FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari. (Haven't tried others.)

FWIW, you can actually implement your own version of `toFixed` per the spec in JS and that behaves as you would expect. See http://jsfiddle.net/joenudell/7qahrb6d/.

Answer (score 0):

Kippie
your solution has problems
one of them

```
39133.005.toFixed(2) => 39133 

var Calc = function () {
    var self = this;

this.float2Array = function(num) {
    var floatString = num.toString(),
        exp = floatString.indexOf(".") - (floatString.length - 1),
        mant = floatString.replace(".", "").split("").map(function (i) { return parseInt(i); });
    return { exp: exp, mant: mant };
};

this.round2 = function (num, dec, sep) {
    var decimal = !!dec ? dec : 2,
    separator = !!sep ? sep : '',
    r = parseFloat(num),
    exp10 = Math.pow(10, decimal);
    r = Math.round(r * exp10) / exp10;

    var rr = Number(r).toFixed(decimal).toString().split('.');

    var b = rr[0].replace(/(\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})+(?:\.\d|\b)))/g, "\$1" + separator);
    r = (rr[1] ? b + '.' + rr[1] : b);

    return r;
};

this.toFixed10 = function (f, num) {
    var prepareInt = self.float2Array(f),
        naturalInt = prepareInt.mant,
        places = Math.abs(prepareInt.exp),
        result = prepareInt.mant.slice(),
        resultFixedLenth;

    // if number non fractional or has zero fractional part
    if (f.isInt()) {
        return f.toFixed(num);
    }
    // if the number of decimal places equals to required rounding
    if (places === num) {
        return Number(f).toString();
    }
    //if number has trailing zero (when casting to string type float 1.0050 => "1.005" => 005 <0050)
    if (places < num) {
        return Number(f).round2(num);
    }

    for (var e = naturalInt.length - (places > num ? (places - num) : 0), s = 0; e >= s; e--) {
        if (naturalInt.hasOwnProperty(e)) {
            if (naturalInt[e] > 4 && naturalInt[e - 1] < 9) {
                result[e] = 0;
                result[e - 1] = naturalInt[e - 1] + 1;
                break;
            } else if (naturalInt[e] > 4 && naturalInt[e - 1] === 9) {
                result[e] = 0;
                result[e - 1] = 0;
                result[e - 2] = naturalInt[e - 2] < 9 ? naturalInt[e - 2] + 1 : 0;
            } else if (e === 0 && naturalInt[e] === 9 && naturalInt[e + 1] === 9) {
                result[e] = 0;
                result.unshift(1);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (places - num > 0) {
        resultFixedLenth = result.slice(0, -(places - num));
    } else {
        for (var i = 0, l = num - places; i < l; i++) {
            result.push(0);
        }
        resultFixedLenth = result;
    }

    return (parseInt(resultFixedLenth.join("")) / Math.pow(10, num)).round2(num);
};
this.polyfill = function() {
    if (!Array.prototype.map) {
        Array.prototype.map = function (callback, thisArg) {
            var T, A, k;
            if (this == null) { throw new TypeError(' this is null or not defined'); }
            var O = Object(this), len = O.length >>> 0;
            if (typeof callback !== 'function') { throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function'); }
            if (arguments.length > 1) { T = thisArg; }

            A = new Array(len);
            k = 0;
            while (k < len) {
                var kValue, mappedValue;
                if (k in O) {
                    kValue = O[k];
                    mappedValue = callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
                    A[k] = mappedValue;
                }
                k++;
            }
            return A;
        };
    }
};

this.init = function () {
    self.polyfill();
    Number.prototype.toFixed10 = function (decimal) {
        return calc.toFixed10(this, decimal);
    }
    Number.prototype.round2 = function (decimal) {
        return calc.round2(this, decimal);
    }
    Number.prototype.isInt = function () {
        return (Math.round(this) == this);
    }
}
}, calc = new Calc(); calc.init();
```

this works good)

Answer (score 0):

```
obj = {
    round(val) {
      const delta = 0.00001
      let num = val
      if (num - Math.floor(num) === 0.5) {
        num += delta
      }
      return Math.round(num + delta)
    },
  fixed(val, count = 0) {
      const power = Math.pow(10, count)
      let res = this.round(val * power) / power
      let arr = `${res}`.split('.')
      let addZero = ''
      for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        addZero += '0'
      }
      if (count > 0) {
        arr[1] = ((arr[1] || '') + addZero).substr(0, count)
      }
      return arr.join('.')
  }
}
obj.fixed(5.175, 2)
```

// "5.18"