# toFixed not working for value 3.675

Tags: javascript, rounding, tofixed

I am facing the issue while round numbers in 2 decimal points using javascript function `toFixed`

It's working for all the values except some cases

For example : 
Value is : `3.675` Then it should be `3.68`

I have tried it as below

```
var ans = Number(DiscountValue).toFixed(2);
```

I have even tried with the following code

```
var ans = parseFloat(DiscountValue).toFixed(2);
```

But its returning `3.67`

Anyone face this issue before

Plz guide how we can sort this !

Comment: First, `toFixed` is a javascript function, not jQuery, second, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808671/javascript-how-to-prevent-tofixed-from-rounding-off-decimal-numbers

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.round(num * 100) / 100
```

It will give you the result you are expecting

Comment: This works (in some sense) in this particular case, but not in all cases.