# Limit precision of the float number without rounding

Tags: javascript

is there a way to have 2 numbers after comma without rounding the value. I want the exact value. `Math.round()` and `toFixed()` give the value rounded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript - how to prevent toFixed from rounding off decimal numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808671/javascript-how-to-prevent-tofixed-from-rounding-off-decimal-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the workaround with help of `Math.ceil()` and `Math.floor()` functions.
Another way, is treat is as an string and use `.slice()`

i.e:

```js
number = number.slice(0, number.indexOf(".")+3); //this should give you 2 decimals
Number(number); //Convert it to "Number" again, so you can operate with it
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution without type conversions

---

While solving the issue, you should bear in mind that bouncing back and forth between data types may cost you [some of app performance wasted](https://jsbench.me/0zkaqov4qq/1)

Instead, I'd suggest to modify input number directly:

- shift the dot `n` positions to the right by multiplying your number by 10 in power of `n` (`10**n`)
- cut off what's left after dot, using bitwise OR (`|`) that implicitly turns the float into integer
- divide the result by 10 in power of `n` to shift the dot `n` positions back to the left

Following is a quick live-demo:

```js
const num = 3.14159265,
      precision = 4,
      
      limitPrecision = (n,p) => (0|n*10**p)/10**p
      
console.log(limitPrecision(num, precision))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```