# How do I format numbers into decimal notation?

Tags: javascript, decimal, number-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display two decimal places, no rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/display-two-decimal-places-no-rounding)

I need to format the total result numbers in 2 decimal format. I am trying to achieve it without using jQuery plugin but just editing my following function:

```
function tally(selector) {
    var total = 0;
    $('p.editable_number').each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).text()) || 0;
        $('#subtotal').html(total)
        $('#total').html(total*0.21);
        $('#total1').html(total*1.21);
    })
}
```

How this is possible modifying the `VAR`? There are other ways to achieve it?

[Here my case](http://jsfiddle.net/Manna/CBk5a/9/), as you can notice i dont get the total result formatted just with decimal separator

Comment: This is JavaScript, not Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#subtotal').html((total).toFixed(2))
$('#total').html((total*0.21).toFixed(2));
$('#total1').html((total*1.21).toFixed(2));
```

One note though: in generic case, where the base is not an integer, it's possible that base + vat != total because of rounding.

Comment: I am trying to implement it on http://jsfiddle.net/Manna/CBk5a/9/ but it s not working

Comment: so anytime i land to the page i get the decimal alert, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to format your total so that it displays with 2 decimals.

Try this:

```
$('#subtotal').html(total.toFixed(2));
```

and so on...

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am doing like this , it does not work neither                 $('#total1').html(total.toFixed(2)*1.21);
$('#total').html(total.toFixed(2)*0.21)

Comment: You must do like this: $('total').html((total *0.21).toFixed(2))