# jquery get the value of one number after the comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am trying to draw a chart using flot jquery library.

I want to this:

if the value is 4.52124515, I want it to be 4.2

if the values is 41.215, i want it to be 41.2

this is my code

```
tickFormatter: function (val, axis) {
                       return val + '%';
                   }
```

the value i am talking about is passing through the `val` variable.

Comment: 41.215.toFixed(1) ? that is just plain javascript btw

Comment: `val.toFixed(1) + '%';` is what you want https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: thank you all i didn't you about it and google did n't help me in it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display two decimal places, no rounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/display-two-decimal-places-no-rounding)

Comment: @Mr_Green not duplicated, because even this toFixed adding aditional zeros as the first answer says that

Comment: @SimeoniPeraparota the duplicate is not using `toFixed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function (val, axis) {                     
    val = Math.round(val * 10) / 10;
    return val + '%';
}
```

using `toFixed` will add additional zeros.

Check the JSFiddle with values like 12.02 to see the difference.
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/grgesxbt/).

Comment: why is that please? could you explain your answer

Comment: Lets say the number is 12.34. multiply by 10 + round -> 123 -> divide by 10 -> 12.3.