# Submit Value to 2 Decimal Places

Tags: javascript

Everything in my script works perfectly except for my last "if" statement, it's failing to execute and I cannot figure it out for the life of me! I know I have an error somewhere but just can't work out why, I'm new to JavaScript.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve on the last statement:-

If  "AgeGrade" variable matches "Expression" variable then accept value and change value entered to 2 decimal points. E.g. If 5.999 entered then change to 5.99

Here's the code:-

```
function agegrade() {

    var AgeGrade = document.submitrunnertime.AgeGrade.value;
    var expression = /^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/

    if (AgeGrade == null || AgeGrade == "") {
        document.submitrunnertime.AgeGrade.value = "-1";
        return true;
    } else if (AgeGrade != document.submitrunnertime.AgeGrade.value.match(expression)) {
        alert("Error - Need a number!");
        return false;
    } else if (AgeGrade == document.submitrunnertime.AgeGrade.value.match(expression)) {
        document.submitrunnertime.AgeGrade.value = AgeGrade.toFixed(2);
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which path is executed?

Comment: You should change your regex to /^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?$/

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/display-two-decimal-places-no-rounding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last `if` statement probably fails with an error like: `AgeGrade.toFixed is not a function`.

How can you fix this?

The `.value()` method you're using returns a string. The method `.toFixed(`), however, works with numbers only ([MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)). Before invoking it, try converting `AgeGrade` to float:

```
document.submitrunnertime.AgeGrade.value = parseFloat(AgeGrade).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.

Although this has now allowed me to submit a value it's rounding the number up rather than stripping the number precisely to 2 decimal places - any ideas?

Comment: As already mentioned, please have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/display-two-decimal-places-no-rounding

Comment: In your specific case, it translates to: `Math.floor(parseFloat(AgeGrade) * 100) / 100`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. i have use it in many javascripts for rounding off

```
document.submitrunnertime.AgeGrade.value = Math.round(AgeGrade * 100) / 100;
```

Comment: The issue is with the `if` statement, not the rounding, as per his question.