# How to format a float to two digit

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to get float with only two number after the `.` :

```
var number = 1.9090909090909092;
var newNumber = (number).toFixed(2);
```

And in `newNumber` i get : `1.91` instead of `1.90`. Any idea why it happen?

Comment: Because it is correct. It is not slicing the later digits. Rather it is rounding off to 2 digits.

Comment: @SameerSawla there is any method that can round the digit down?

Comment: I was to give the solution as cpolito gave. You could do that way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display two decimal places, no rounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/display-two-decimal-places-no-rounding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to format a float to any number of digits use this function:

```
function truncate(num, pos) {

    return Math.floor(num*Math.pow(10, pos))/Math.pow(10, pos);

}
```

where num is the float and pos is the number of digits you want after the decimal.

Answer (score -1):

He approximate The number

Example

25.65 = 25.7

5.699 = 5.70

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer