# toFixed method without rounding to five digit

Tags: javascript, jquery, floating-point, rounding

I have a number `var x = 2.305185185185195;`

```
x = x.toFixed(5);
```

`x = 2.30519` but I require this without rounding i.e. `2.30518`

I read some thread with two decimal places but could not find for five decimal places.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display two decimal places, no rounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/display-two-decimal-places-no-rounding)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use an apropriate factor and floor it and return the result of the division.

Basically this solution moves the point to the left with a factor of 10^d and gets an integer of that and divided the value with the former factor to get the right digits.

```js
function getFlooredFixed(v, d) {
    return (Math.floor(v * Math.pow(10, d)) / Math.pow(10, d)).toFixed(d);
}

var x = 2.305185185185195;

document.write(getFlooredFixed(x, 5));
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L00g8bwj/1/ `slice()` work 3 times faster with nums < 1.000, and 7 times faster with numbers < 1.000.000... (`slice()` work time = `const`, it doesn't depends from numbers)

Comment: `getFlooredFixed(4.27, 5)` ==> `4.26999`

Comment: `getFlooredFixed(10.20, 2)` ==> `10.19`

Comment: @RomanBelov, with some numbers, it does not work, because the value is not convertable to float with al necessary digits.

Answer (score 4):

If you need only a "part" of a number with a floating point without rounding, you can just "cut" it:

```
function cutNumber(number, digitsAfterDot) {
    const str = `${number}`;

    return str.slice(0, str.indexOf('.') + digitsAfterDot + 1);
}

const x = 2.305185185185195;

console.log(cutNumber(x, 5)); // 2.30518
```

This method is fast (https://jsfiddle.net/93m8akzo/1/) and its execution time doesn't depend on `number` or `digitsAfterDot` values.

You can also "play around" with both functions in a given fiddle for a better understanding of what they do.

---

You can read more about `slice()` method here - [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

---

**NOTE** This function is only an example, don't use it in production applications.
You should definitely add input values validation and errors handling!

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer

Comment: cutNumber(0.11111111111111125, 17) -> '0.11111111111111124'

Answer (score 1):

> The Math.trunc() function returns the integer part of a number by
>   removing any fractional digits

So you can multiply the number by 10^n where n is the desired number of precision, truncate the decimal part using `Math.trunc()`, divide by the same number (10^n) and apply `toFixed()` to format it (in order to get the form of 2.30 instead of 2.3 for example)

```
var x = 2.305185185185195;

console.log((Math.trunc(x*100000)/100000).toFixed(5));
```

Comment: @FZs added description.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted it out by adding a small amount if the decimal is 5, then rounding as usual:

`function(value, decimals) {

    var decimals = decimals || 2;

    if( isNaN(value) ){ return 0; }
        
    var decimalPart = value.toString().trim().split('.').pop(),
        extra       = decimalPart.substr(decimals, decimalPart.length - decimals);

    if( extra == '5' && 
        decimalPart.length > decimals
    ){
        value = parseFloat(value) + (1 / ( Math.pow(10, decimals + 5) ) );  
    }

    return Number( parseFloat( value ).toFixed( decimals ) );
        
}`