# How to fix a number to two decimal points with no rounding applied?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have number saying `15.67789`.

I want to display only **two numbers after the decimal point** (i.e 15.67) with out doing any rounding on the number.

For Eg:

15.67789.toFixed(2) returns `15.68` instead

I want to display only `15.67`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display two decimal places, no rounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/display-two-decimal-places-no-rounding)

Comment: Make it a string and split two places after the decimal point.

Comment: Can you explore toPrecision function??

Comment: dirty, but working: `'15.67789'.substr(0,'15.67789'.indexOf('.')+3)`

Comment: @shilly / k102 ,instead of converting a number to String and performing substring operation. Do we have any math approach ?

Comment: Read the link alan posted, it has the math approach you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/display-two-decimal-places-no-rounding Please refer this link, Hope it will help you

Comment: @Ruhul Cannot rely on toPrecision function. Try out its behaviour with a number 0.001658853

  var num = 0.001658853;
num.toPrecision(2) returns 0.0017 which is not expected.

Comment: Please at the link at mentioned by @Alanfabeta.

Comment: @Alanfabeta / Ruhul
Above link suggests using  floor function.
Math.floor(4.27*100)/100 which is returning 4.26.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex:

edit: I modified regex to accept numbers without decimal places and numbers with one decimal place (thanks @Mi-Creativity):

```
var num = 134.35324; 
num.toString().match(/^(\d*(\.\d{0,2})?)/)[0];
```

Working example https://jsfiddle.net/yevwww8m/2/

Using `substr`:

```
var num = 15.67789;
num = num.toString().substr(0,'15.67789'.indexOf('.')+3);
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/pmmy9o3r/

Just for fun, using regex replace:

```
var num = 15.57789; 
num = num.toString().replace(/^(\d+\.\d{2}).*/g, '$1');
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/4eq3jd4e/

Comment: The first method will fail and throw an error on numbers with no decimal places and numbers with one decimal place [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/kpno14f1/) .. you should use **`/^(\d*(\.\d{0,2})?)/`** instead.

Comment: Also, if the O.P needs to have 2 decimal places always, you should use `toFixed(2)` in all three ways

Comment: Actually using `/^(\d*(\.\d{1,2})?)/` makes more sense because if it has zero decimal places it would not have a decimal point. Another thing that you might want to take in considration is, if a string ( like `foo` ) is passed to the 2nd and 3rd methods it will pass as match! [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kpno14f1/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('app', [])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app='app'>
<input type='number' ng-model='tex' />
{{tex|number:2}}
</body>
```

use the `number` filter to specify the number of digits to be displayed after the decimal point.

Comment: Did OP mention of using Angular?

Comment: it does have angular tag

Comment: Then why angularJS tag is added to the question

Comment: @StarkButtowski Good point, you are right, there is angular tag, my apologies.

Comment: yeah, I was even looking for angular approach.

Comment: even the above snippet do rounding to the nearest value.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Simply multiply the number by 100 to move the point two decimal places, floor it then divide it by 100

```js
var nums = [15.67789, 101.62, 134.35324, 0.00658853, 0.002422, 4.27, 1.1095];

for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
  var temp = nums[i] * 100;
  temp = (('' + temp).split('.')[1] !== '99999999999994') ? (Math.floor(temp) / 100) : nums[i];
  console.log(temp.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: Previously you was rounding number, didn't use `floor` and `toFixed`. I canceled my downvote, it seems now your code is working properly.

Comment: @Techie_Learner, how about the answer now?

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Looks good. hope this works out let me try with few more numbers too .

Comment: Even if this works properly it's just looking horrible really. So complicated and dirty (more dirty then using `regex` or `substr`).

Comment: @ofca, which one is better between the three ways you used in your answer?? using `.substr(0,'15.67789'.indexOf('.')+3)` or `.match(/^(\d*\.\d{2})/)[0];`, or `.replace(/^(\d+\.\d{2}).*/g, '$1')` ??

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? I just thinking that `regex`/`substr` are simpler.

Comment: ok let me rephrase, which way of the three you used in your question is more dirty and complicated than the other two?

Comment: If I needed to use it I would prefere `substr` over regex because of performance (I assume it's faster) and because it's easy to understand.

Comment: Ok, then since you prefer using `substr`, because you assume it's faster and easier to understand, why did you use two other ways beside it in your answer??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121834/discussion-between-ofca-and-mi-creativity).