# Shorten Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I was searching a way to only display two decimals of a variable and I found the `.toFixed()` function, but it rounds the final number, I came across this page [Display two decimal places, no rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/display-two-decimal-places-no-rounding), where one guy says about this method: `.toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/)[0]`, which works perfectly fine, but it's too long. I tryed doing this:

```
function twoDecimals(i) {
i = Number(i.toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/)[0]);
}
```

*.toString() makes it a string, so I use Number() to make it back a variable*

and then I do this:

```
var num = 12.34567;
num.twoDecimals(this);
```

Basically I want to make `.twoDecimals()` equal to `.toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/)[0]` or even better if it has `Number()` surrounding all

Comment: You can't assign to the caller's variable from a function call.

Comment: "...but it's too long" what makes you say it's too long? Is there a tax on the number of characters you can use? Are you attempting to participate in a code golf? Shortening code beyond the point of readability is a sure fire way to make sure that future you won't have a clue what past you was trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
Number.prototype.twoDecimals = function(){
    return (Number)(this.toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/));
}
var num = 12.34567;
console.log(num.twoDecimals()); // Print out 12.34
```

Comment: I recommend you should read about javascript prototype. For example : https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/understanding-javascript-prototypes

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
Number.prototype.twoDecimals = function(arg){
    return arg.toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/)
}
```

This should give all objects of the `Number` class a new method called `twoDecimals`.