# Remove numbers after decimal in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var randomNumber = (Math.random()*3 + 3.5); randomNumber;

alert(randomNumber)
```

This piece of code returns a number like

**4.589729345235789**

I need it to return

**4.5**

So need it to remove all the numbers after the decimal except the first one, can anyone show me how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to set the amount of decimal places in a number, you can use `toFixed(X)`, where X is the amount of decimal places you want to have.

For example,

`4.589729345235789.toFixed(1);` would result in `4.6`.

Keep in mind, this will convert the number into a string.

If you need absolute accuracy and `4.6` is not good enough for you, see [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/display-two-decimal-places-no-rounding), which has this as a more "accurate" method for your case:

`var with2Decimals = num.toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/)[0]`

Notice the `{0,2}` inside of that, which is the range. You can change it to `{0,1}` in your case.

Comment: It will return 4.6 not 4.5

Answer (score 5):

You use `Number.prototype.toPrecision()` with parameter `2`, `Number.prototype.toFixed()` with parameter `1`.

```
+randomNumber.toPrecision(2);
```

Alternatively, you can use `String.prototype.slice()` with parameters `0`, `3`

```
+String(randomNumber).slice(0, 3);
```