# Different result after subtraction in script

Tags: javascript

Why is different result in variable "pisa" in this script ? When I use ".toString" is not the same value like when I write value in quotation mark.  I need value like in second script. Thank you very much.

```js
// first script
var cez = 45.30;
var bar = (cez).toString();
var convertedTime = (Number(bar.split('.')[0]) * 60 + Number(bar.split('.')[1])) * 60000;
var pisa = convertedTime;
console.log(pisa); // 162180000

// first script
var bar = '45.30';
var convertedTime = (Number(bar.split('.')[0]) * 60 + Number(bar.split('.')[1])) * 60000;
var pisa = convertedTime;
console.log(pisa); //163800000
```

Comment: I would say that in first case `bar.split('.')[1]`  returns 3, and in second case it returns 30

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that doing `(cez).toString()` will truncate the last 0 so you'll get `45.3` and `bar.split('.')[1])` will be 3 instead of 30 in the first case

Comment: Aha, thank you. I understand. It is possible solve this problem with "0" ?

Comment: You could use toFixed() as explained here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp. Given your context, you should however do this only if the second decimal is `0` otherwise, you'll incur rounding.

Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/display-two-decimal-places-no-rounding

Comment: Thank you very much, this solve my problem. I use  "(45.30).toFixed(2)". Thank you :)