# how to show two digits after decimal in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jsp

I am using `JSP` for view. I am using `angularjs` and `javascript`

I have a text box, in that text box there is a value called `12.542001`. The `ng-model` should contain the same but when I am showing I want to show `12.54` only on the text box.

If I work with `toFixed(2)`, Then it will round the value, but I don't want to round that value...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truncate number to two decimal places without rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/truncate-number-to-two-decimal-places-without-rounding)

Comment: its duplicate....  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/truncate-number-to-two-decimal-places-without-rounding

Comment: When you say text box, do you mean an input text control? If so, is it read only? If not, what happens when the user changes the input?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
console.log(parseFloat(Math.round(12.542001 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));

//or use 

num = "122.542001";
var spV= num.split(".");
console.log(spV[0] +"."+ spV[1].substring(0,2));
```

### Update

If your ng-model name is `$scope.totalnumber`. then try this

```
$scope.totalnumber = parseFloat(Math.round($scope.totalnumber * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: this will effect to ng-model, I don't want to round it.Just I want to show the two digits afterdecimal and the ng-model should contain the original value

Comment: perhaps use Math.floor() instead of Math.round()

Comment: I think my explanation is not clear.... ng-model should contain ==>12.542001   but I want to should in the text box 12.54

Comment: @user9130953 then you should be use separate `ng-model` to one for formatted value and another one for real value. the formatted value is assign to the text box