# Get two digits after point for float

Tags: ios, floating-point

I have a float value as `float s = 1.270001` . I need to get two digits as output i.e `1.27` . But when we use `%0.02f` it gives output as `1.28`

How to get two digits after decimal point
ex: `1.16 as 1.16` only

```
`1.89  as 1.89` only but not `1.90`
```

Comment: Here is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/truncate-number-to-two-decimal-places-without-rounding/46171960#46171960

Comment: float s = 1.270001 ; long v = s*100;  (@"%0.02f", v/100.0);

Comment: Defining `s` with `float s = 1.270001` and printing it using `%0.02f` should not produce “1.28”. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `NumberFormatter`

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale.current
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.roundingMode = .floor
let stringValue = formatter.string(from:1.270001)!
print(stringValue)
```

**Output:**

```
1.27
```