# How to use local storage for a currency switcher?

Tags: local-storage

I'm using the following html/ JavaScript **currency switcher** which works fine, BUT I want to add local storage to save the settings after page refresh.
For example when a user or a website visitor switches the currency to another the details get saved even after reloading the page.
Here is my HTML and JavaScript CODE:

```js
$(function() {
  console.clear();
  var rates = {
    'USD': {
      'val': 1,
      'sign': '$',
      'name': 'Dollar'
    },
    'EUR': {
      'val': 1.2,
      'sign': '€',
      'name': 'Euro'
    },
    'CAD': {
      'val': 18,
      'sign': 'C$',
      'name': 'Canadian Dollar'
    },
    'AUD': {
      'val': 3.8,
      'sign': 'A$',
      'name': 'Australian Dollar'
    },
  };
  // Create the List of Available Rates
  var list = ''
  var i = 0;
  $.each(rates, function(key, value) {

    list += `

`;
    i++;
  });
  // Inject The Rates into their Container Using Data Attributes
  $('[data-currency-list]').html(list);
  // Add Event Handler For To change the currency for available rates on click
  var rateKey;
  $('[data-currency]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var currentRate = $(this).attr('data-currency');

    if (currentRate == rateKey) {
      return;
    }
    rateKey = currentRate;
    var rateInfo = rates[currentRate];

    $('[data-price]').each(function() {
      var $el = $(this);
      var price = $el.attr('data-price');
      var newVal = price * rateInfo.val;
      /*  Display two decimal places, no rounding
       *  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/display-two-decimal-places-no-rounding
       */
      var roundedVal = newVal.toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/)[0]
      var el = $el[0];
      // console.log(el);
      el.childNodes[0].nodeValue = roundedVal + ' ' + rateInfo.sign;

    })
    var event = $.Event('currency-change');
    event.rate = rateInfo;
    $(document).trigger(event);

  })
  var to, to2,to3;
  $(document).on('currency-change', function(e) {
    var rate = e.rate;
    var heading = $('<h1 id="heading"></h1>');
    var message = '<span>the currency was changed to : ' + rate.name + '</span><a href="#close" id="close-heading">close</a>';

    heading.html($(message));
    if (!$('#heading').length > 0) {
      $('.price-list').before($(heading));
    }

  
    if (to) {
      clearTimeout(to);
    }
    if (to2) {
      clearTimeout(to2);
    }
    if (to3) {
      clearTimeout(to3);
    }
   if( $('#heading').hasClass('fade-in')){
     console.log('IF');
       $('#heading').removeClass('fade-in');
    to = setTimeout(function() {     
      $('#heading')
        .html(message)
        .addClass('fade-in');
      console.log('first');
      to2 = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#heading').removeClass('fade-in');
        console.log('second');
      }, 2000)
    },300);
     
      }else{   
        console.log('ELSE');
        $('#heading')
          .html(message)
          .addClass('fade-in');
        console.log('first');
        to2 = setTimeout(function() {
          $('#heading').removeClass('fade-in');
          console.log('second');
        }, 2000)

      }
  //  console.log(e.rate);
  })
$(document).on('click','#close-heading',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#heading').removeClass('fade-in');
      if (to) {
      clearTimeout(to);
    }
    if (to2) {
      clearTimeout(to2);
    }
})
})
```

```html
</div>
<li><a  href="#" data-currency="USD">US Dollars</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-currency="CAD">CA Dollars</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-currency="AUD">AU Dollars</a></li>
  <li><a  href="#" data-currency="EUR">Euors</a></li>
</div>

<div><span class="price" data-price="10">10 $</span></div>
```

Could somebody change the code adding *LocalStorage*?
I would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can save a variable to local storage like this:
`localStorage.setItem("foo", "bar");` and you can then retrieve it again like this: `localStorage.getItem("foo");`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please ad it to MY code as Im new to JS?