# showing the exact decimal (not rounding) javascritp / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, decimal

what i want is just to show the result of a variable with just one number after the ".".
i've tried *toFixed* and *toPrecision* but they round the whole number, and i want the result to be exact
in:

```
var result = 6.853571428571428; //
$("#id").html(result); //want to show 6.8
```

i want to show just the "6.8", using functions like `toFixed(2)` and `toPrecision(2)` gives me **6.9**.
also tried `Math.round(number * 10) / 10` but with the same results

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truncate number to two decimal places without rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/truncate-number-to-two-decimal-places-without-rounding)

Comment: i've tried that, even in the example, they are rounding 15.7784514 to 17.8, i'd like to get just the 1st number after ".", in the example you gave me should be 17.7 instead if 17.8 :)

Comment: just slightly adjust the regex in the answer `var with1Decimals = num.toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?/)[0]`  https://jsfiddle.net/xeqfb2vd/

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = 6.853571428571428;
$("#id").html(Math.trunc(result*10)/10);
```

Comment: This is alot prettier than my eyesore! `$("#id").html((+((""+(result*10)).split('.')[0])/10))` - thanks for sharing. i didn't know about `Math.trunc`

Answer (score 0):

[check other and complete solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/truncate-number-to-two-decimal-places-without-rounding)

```
    var result = 6.853571428571428; 
    result = result.toString(); //pars it to String 
    result = result.slice(0, (result.indexOf("."))+2);
    console.log(Number(result));
```