# php function to convert numbers into currency format

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP number_format is rounding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087628/php-number-format-is-rounding)

I need a PHP function to convert numbers into currency format like so:

```
444 output 444.00
444.156 output 444.15
0 output 0.00
```

**It should not round off the last decimal digit.**

Comment: You are looking for [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

Comment: what do you want for (1.569 = 1.56 or 1.57)?

Answer (score 1):

try [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) method. It will get the job done for you.

```
$number = 444.657;

$format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 444.66
```

## Without Rounding

```
substr(number_format($number, 3, '.', ''), 0, -1);
//444.65
```

Comment: 12457 output shoul be 123457.00

Comment: echo number_format('444.156', 2); //444.16! please include this part also

Comment: 1245.649 output 12456.64