# Format a float to two decimal places

Tags: php, string

I want to format a float value I have to two decimal places.

For example if I have a float for a price of `5.2`, I want it to be formatted as `5.20`.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Answer (score 74):

Try [`number_format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
echo number_format("5.2",2)
```

Comment: [This might also be helpful.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

Comment: Keep in mind that number_format returns a string, so your float will no longer be of type float. if you try and use the resulting number in calculations you may get undesirable results. You can cast it back to a float by wrapping it in floatval()

Comment: Note: `+number_format("5.2",2);` will give you a number as opposed to `number_format("5.2",2)` which gives a string. Anyways, `sprintf('%0.2f', $num)` has always been my preference in general situations. Never had a valid reason to do a benchmark test, let me know in case you have a valid reason to use otherwise except personal preference(or context). Cheers!

Comment: Note: number_format will round up your numbers... 
for example number_format('21.188624', 2, ',', ' ') is 21,19. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833137/how-to-make-number-format-not-to-round-numbers-up

Comment: IMPORTANT: If you want to do calculations with the result, as Baxny mentioned, casting `number_format(n > 999, 2)` will result in `1`. You can't cast or calculate a number string with a comma in it, so make sure to remove that: `number_format('5.2', 2, '.', '');`

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to use `printf` or `sprintf`. You can read more about it in the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

Answer (score 3):

If you're simply trying to ensure a number is displayed with two decimal places, you could also use [number_format](http://www.php.net/number_format), or (if this is a currency value) [money_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php).

e.g.: `echo number_format('5.2', 2);`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
number_format((float)$foo, 2, '.', '');
```

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of how your code solves the problem at hand.

Comment: @Matt this answer is good enough.. look at the top answer its exactely the same...