# PHP Round() not working properly

Tags: php, math

I need help. I'm doing this:

```
round($myvar,2);
```

And this is the number I'm getting: 9.779999999999999€

With the other variables it works just fine, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What else are you doing after rounding? How are you displaying this value?

Comment: `round($myvar,2)` does not produce any output, probably you're doing some `echo` or `print`, show us full code

Comment: I'm simply using echo...
<?php echo round($R_ganhoComercial,2); ?>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435556/format-a-float-to-two-decimal-places

Comment: Will that round the number too or just cut it ?

Comment: What is the value of $R_ganhoComercial @PabloCamara ?

Comment: Maybe it could be useful if you provide the part of code that produces the variable that you want to round. Is it really sure, that you provide a float?

Comment: That won't display `€`, so what exactly are you displaying? What does a var_dump() of `$R_ganhoComercial` give?

Comment: You guys try it: 9.7752
Try rounding that number, I'm trying to get 9.78 or something like that, but it returns 9.779999999999999...

Comment: @MarkBaker forget the € part that was added in the HTML part, try to round(9.7752,2) , doesn't work right o.O

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/1MTg6e works for me

Comment: What is the `precision` setting in your `php.ini` configuration? Has it been changed from the default value of `14`?

Comment: @Dagon I just tried this exact code: <?php echo round(9.7752,2);?> and it doesn't work like yours

Comment: @MarkBaker I don't know but I think that might be it, if thats the case how would I fix it?

Comment: If it is `precision`, either  change it in your `php.ini` file, or use [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Comment: You can try number_format(round(myvar, 2), 2); but its only for display.

Comment: your precision looks to be  16, the default is 12 `ini_set("precision", 12);`

Comment: @MarkBaker what if i don't have access to change ini settings on a shared server?

Comment: @AhmedAli - Well if they're not using the default precision setting for precision, and they won't let you change it, then you change your provider

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP7.1 json\_encode() Float Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981409/php7-1-json-encode-float-issue)

Answer (score 24):

I did this:

```
<?php echo round(9.7752,2);?>
```

And I got: 9.779999999999999

I believe it's something in php.ini as @MarkBaker said..
But, I fixed it by doing:

```
<?php echo number_format($myvar,2);
```

And I got exactly what I wanted.
Thanks guys for the help!

Comment: `ini_set("precision", 12);` should also work, editing php.ini would make it easier

Comment: This just seems like normal [floating point inaccuracy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726721/php-math-precision) to me...

Comment: Alright, thanks for helping, next time I'll know what to do, got it fixed (Y)

Comment: Note that number_format() will add commas to large numbers. That may or may not be useful output, depending on your circumstances.

Answer (score 11):

Just join empty string before round function like

```
$val = "" . round(9.597466245, 2);
```

Comment: probably the simplest one

Comment: what a strange solution, but it worked!

Answer (score 8):

what problem I encounter is that round(18.203,2) = 18.2 ,then json_encode(...) = 18.199999999 .
so I find the solution is  json_encode(strval(round(18.203,2)))  = 18.2
it works

Comment: This fixed my issue

Answer (score 3):

something (could be in some 3rd party code ?) set your ini setting `precision` to `16`

```
$php -a
php > echo ini_get("precision");
14 // default 
php > echo round(9.7752,2);
9.78

php > echo ini_set("precision", 16);
14
php > echo round(9.7752,2);
9.779999999999999
```

Answer (score 2):

Just encase the result in a floatval

```
floatval(round($myvar,2));
```

If you use `number_format`, you **must add the next two parameters** otherwise larger numbers will go wrong:

```
number_format($myvar,2, '.', '');
```

This tells PHP to use "." as the decimal separator and no thousands separator.

Answer (score 0):

Although OP solved his issue, I saw this while searching for other (but similar) issue.

If you came here with a problem where PHP's `round()` function is misbehaving (i.e. `round(1.4447, 2)` will output `1.44` instead of `1.45`) that's because round looks just 1 decimal position away from the needed precision, here's a small recursive helper function that solves the issue:

```
function roundFloat($float, $neededPrecision, $startAt = 7)
{
    if ($neededPrecision < $startAt) {
        $startAt--;
        $newFloat = round($float, $startAt);
        return roundFloat($newFloat, $neededPrecision, $startAt);
    }

    return $float;
}
```

Usage example:

```
roundFloat(1.4447, 2, 5); // Returns 1.45
```

Explanation:

- In example above, it starts rounding from 5th decimal point (`0`) in this case since not stated otherwise.
- You can call the function like `roundFloat(1.4447, 2, 15)` with same
  outcome for given float `1.4447`.
- `$startAt` just defines the starting point for the "rounding process" or the required precision.

Note: all programming languages have issues with writing some floats precisely (has to do with binary, google that for more info).

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: `round(1.4447, 2)` -should- return 1.44; that is the nearest 2-decimal-digit float.

Comment: your solution is not how rounding works, your are rounding a rounded number, which is bad

Comment: rounding can only be applied once, if applied >1 time it may yield incorrect results

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my workaround (in order to not change the ini-file and possibly break something else):

```
$rounded = bcdiv($number, 1, 2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Combining @PabloCamara's answer and the comment from @LorienBrune, this solution worked for me:

```
function roundFixed($number, $decimalPlaces)
{
    return str_replace(',', '', number_format($number, $decimalPlaces));
}
```