# How to json_encode float values in PHP 7.1.1?

Tags: php, json

PHP seems to have [a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72567) in the way it handles decimal precision in json_encode.

It's easy to see just by encoding a simple float:

```
echo json_encode(["testVal" => 0.830]);

// Prints out:
{"testVal":0.82999999999999996003197111349436454474925994873046875}
```

I'm not much of a server admin, so aside from going into the php.ini and changing `serialize_precision` to -1, is there anything I can do in my code to protect against this when I can't be sure it's running in an environment where that setting has been changed?

EDIT: 
I'm sure some comments will want to link against general discussions of why floating point imprecision exists. I know that. My question here is specifically about the best practice for dealing with it in PHP, and whether there is a way to code defensively against it. Surely there is a better way than sending floats as strings.

Comment: Does this happen in 7.0 as well?

Comment: As the discussion on the bug report you linked to makes clear, this is not a bug but a deliberate feature. If your server is configured to serialize floating point numbers with high precision, `json_encode` will now respect this.

Comment: And if you write that value as string? Then you have exact that number you want.

Comment: `0.830` cannot be represented exactly as floating point. It is an approximation. PHP provides a better approximation (with a lot of decimal places). That's all. You can format the value as string using `number_format()` and put the string in JSON. Or, better, you can let it be a floating point number and do the formatting just before you want to put the value on screen.

Answer (score 11):

You should configure '[precision](http://php.net/precision)' and 'serialize_precision' params.

```
precision = 14
serialize_precision = -1
```

Test case:

```
php -r 'ini_set("precision", 14); ini_set("serialize_precision", -1); var_dump(json_encode(["testVal" => 0.830]));'
string(16) "{"testVal":0.83}"
```

Comment: It might be helpful to link to the [documentation changelog](//php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-changelog), where it is documented what changed. In particular, changing the `precision` no longer has an effect on `json_encode`.

Comment: @Justastudent Thanks, thats true for 7.1, many guys still use 5.6 so answer above will be useful for everybody who use 5.6+.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned this in my original question. Is this the best solution, and if so, why? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: @GoldenJoe I think `serialize_precision = -1` is more convenient than using `number_format` across the code. It's possible to create `.user.ini` in site public dir and then add `serialize_precision = -1` option to it.

Comment: Although not without its limits, a simple fix is to cast the value as a string. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50944401/2338825