# PHP & JSON | Json encode adding to many zeros to a value

Tags: php, json

I am working on a extremely simple API project and everything works the way its supposed to, until I use `json_encode()`. When I go to https://phoenix.ltda/api/index.php?version=1.3 it returns `{"version":1.4000000000000001}`. How would I remove the extra zeros and only get `1.4`? This problem only occurs when I use `json_decode()`. How would I fix this? Would I use PHP's `round()`?

**index.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['version'])){
    $current_version = $_GET['version'];
    require_once 'includes/updates.php';
    $next_version = get_updated_version($current_version);
    $encode = array('version' => $next_version);
    $next_version = json_encode($encode);
    echo $next_version;
}

?>
```

**updates.php**

```
<?php

function get_updated_version($version){
    $string = $version+'.1';
    return $string;
}

?>
```

**EDIT:**
Problem also occurs when I pass numbers such as 1.6 and 1.1.

Comment: do `json_encode(array('version' => (string)$next_version))` https://3v4l.org/T4OAh or fix precision, is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981409/php7-1-json-encode-float-issue

Answer (score 0):

Use `round()` to get rid of excess digits.

```
function get_updated_version($version){
    $string = round($version + .1, 3);
    return $string;
}
```

This will have at most 3 digits after the decimal point.

See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for the root cause.