# php json_encode adds decimal to integer?

Tags: php, php-7.2

I tested it, but it's like this in only one part

As integer 125398460000 goes through json_encode

I've seen it change to 125398459999.99998.

125398460001 or 125398470000 did not.

Am I mistaken now?

Any guesses as to why this happened?

Comment: At a guess I'd say that you're running a 32-bit build of PHP, and those numbers are too big for an integer. What you're seeing is the rounding errors that occur with floating point numbers

Comment: Show us the code and we might do more than guess.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981409/php7-1-json-encode-float-issue