# how to get exactly 2 value after decimal point in php

Tags: php

```
$a =99.99999;
echo $f = sprintf ("%.2f", $a);
```

output value is `100.00`

But i need `99.99`

can any one help this please

Comment: 99.99999 rounded to 2 decimal places is 100.00. 99.99 would be incorrect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places 

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

http://3v4l.org/LdHLA

```
echo intval((99.99999*100))/100;
```

Taken from here:

[How to make number_format() not to round numbers up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833137/how-to-make-number-format-not-to-round-numbers-up)

Comment: i no need to round the amount. can u say how to display 99.99 instead of 99.9999

Comment: @user2235324 look at the link I gave you. http://3v4l.org/LdHLA. It is providing an output of 99.99, with no rounding.

Comment: Then you tested it wrong. This works: echo intval((99.99999*100))/100; You'll get 99.99.

Answer (score 0):

use below code you will get required one

```
echo number_format($a,2);
```