# PHP float calculation error when subtracting

Tags: php, math, floating-point, formatting

I have a very strange issue. If I subtract 2 float vars where one is the result of a mathematical operation I get a wrong value.

Example:

```
var_dump($remaining);
var_dump($this->hours_sub['personal']);
echo $remaining-$this->hours_sub['personal'];
```

This it the output:

```
float 5.4
float 1.4
5.3290705182008E-15
```

**5.4-1.4** should be **4**
If I add the two values the result is correct.

Where is my mistake?
It can not be a rounding issue.

Comment: It is [working fine](http://ideone.com/rgr6h6), maybe you should try [`bcsub()`](http://php.net/bcsub)

Comment: Why "It can not be a rounding issue."?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Because a rounding issue would not produce a value close to 0 for the difference of two approximations to 5.4 and 1.4 respectively. A "rounding issue" would produce `3.999...9xyz` or `4.000...0xyz`.

Comment: Ia am sorry for the question. It was stupid. For everyone who has the same problem. You must cast floatvals to the to the same format using round() or number_format(). See http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.float.php

Comment: Highly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 119):

If still somebody hits this page with similar problems where floating number subtraction causes error or strange values.
Below I will explain this problem with a bit more details.

It is not directly related to PHP and it is not a bug.
However, every programmer should be aware of this issue.

This problem even took many lives two decades ago.

On 25 February 1991 an incorrect floating-point arithmetic (called rounding error) in a MIM-104 Patriot missile battery prevented it from intercepting an incoming Scud missile in Dhahran, Saudi Arabia, killing 28 soldiers and injuring near 100 servicemen from the U.S. Army's 14th Quartermaster Detachment.

But why it happens?

The reason is that floating point values represent a limited precision. So, a value might
not have the same string representation after any processing (chopped off). It also
includes writing a floating point value in your script and directly
printing it without any mathematical operations.

Just a simple example:

```
$a = '36';
$b = '-35.99';
echo ($a + $b);
```

You'd think, "Hey, that should give me `0.01`, right?" But instead, the computer says, "Nope, it's `0.009999999999998`." Why? It's all down to how the computer deals with numbers.

Like whole numbers (which we call integers), floating point numbers (fractions) double or float is stored in memory as a string of 0's and 1's. How decimals differ from integers is in how we interpret the 0's and 1's when we want to look at them. There are some standards how they are stored (particularly, IEEE 754 standard).

Floating-point numbers are typically packed into a computer datum as the sign bit, the exponent field, and the significand or mantissa, from left to right....

Decimal numbers are not well represented in binary due to lack of enough space. So, you can't express `1/3` exactly as it's `0.3333333...`, right? Why we can't represent `0.01` as a binary float number is for the same reason. `1/100` is `0.00000010100011110101110000.....` with a repeating `10100011110101110000`.

If `0.01` is kept in simplified and system-truncated form of `01000111101011100001010` in binary, when it is translated back to decimal, it would be read like `0.0099999....` depending on system (64bit computers will give you much better precision than 32-bits). Operating system decides in this case whether to print it as it sees or how to make it in more human-readable way. So, it is machine-dependent how they want to represent it. But it can be protected in language level with different methods.

If you format the result using

```
echo number_format(0.009999999999998, 2);
```

it will print `0.01`.

It is because in this case you instruct how it should be read and how precision you require.

Note number_format() is not the only function, a few other functions and ways can be used to tell the programming language about the precision expectation.

It is similar in other languages. For example, in Python, the decimal module provides arbitrary precision arithmetic. In Java, the BigDecimal class can be used. Besides using these built-in features, you can also use libraries that provide arbitrary precision arithmetic, or adjust your program's logic to minimize the impact of floating point errors.

To recap, floating point errors are a consequence of the limited number of bits available for storing numerical data. It's not solely a problem of representation in binary but the issue also arises from trying to represent an infinite number of real numbers with a finite number of bits.

**References:**
https://sdqweb.ipd.kit.edu/publications/pdfs/saglam2016a.pdf
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error

Comment: how to fix this ?

Comment: Decades will go and I will always say that **this is an OBVIOUS BUG**.  We don't care if it saves with `0` and `1` combination or whetever - The inventors should had invented solution for this, without forcing us to learn custom programming for just to calculate `36-35.99`  (i.e. save it as string at first and convert back to number -  **we just don't care**. We need computer to calculate the simple things correctly, without any need to know the internals of `float`) .

Comment: I have already spent hour to just get the answer `945252744562139136 - 1`, searched google several times for a code which can just get that simple answer correctly in `php` but haven't yet found.

Comment: @T.Todua for big numbers / better precision try using for example: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php

Comment: i don't think so. they used 16bit, instead of 32bit. it was discovered 16bit wasn't enough when calculation trajectory, vector, etc.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
<?php
    $a = 96.35;
    $b = 96.01;

    $c = ( ( floor($a * 100) - floor($b * 100) ) / 100 );

    echo $c; // should see 0.34 exactly instead of 0.33999999999999
?>
```

Since the problem occurs with floating point subtraction operation I decided to eliminate that by transforming it into an integer operation, then backing up the result into a floating point again.

I much prefer that solution because basically it does prevent the error on calculation rather than rouding up the result with other functions.

Comment: There are still examples where this does not work. Adding round gave me good results:
$c = ( ( floor(round($a, 2) * 100) - floor(round($b, 2) * 100) ) / 100 );

Answer (score 5):

In addition to using number_format(), there are three other ways to obtain the correct result.  One involves doing a little math, as follows:

```
<?php

$a = '36';
$b = '-35.99';

$a *= 100;
$b *= 100;

echo (($a + $b)/100),"\n";
```

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/PJMAn)

Or, you could simply use printf():

```
<?php

$a = '36';
$b = '-35.99';

printf("\n%.2f",($a+$b));
```

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/HnDYR)

Note, without the precision specifier, the printf() result will contain trailing zero decimals, as follows: `0.010000`

You also could also utilize the BC Math function bcadd(), as follows:

```
<?php
$a = '36';
$b = '-35.99';
echo "\n",bcadd($a,$b,2);
```

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/qh1jQ)

Comment: Used your printf solution `$result = sprintf("%.2f", $result);`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple function to deal with this.
It works similarly to the bcadd function from the bcmath extension of php.
You pass it 2 decimal numbers in string form, $a and $b, and specify how many decimals should be used which must match the number of decimals in both $a and $b.

As you can see it will use integers to do the math, then convert back to string without using floating point operations at any point.

```
function decimalAdd($a,$b,$numDecimals=2) {
    $intSum=(int)str_replace(".","",$a)+(int)str_replace(".","",$b);
    $paddedIntSum=str_pad(abs($intSum),$numDecimals,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $result=($intSum<0?"-":"").($intSum<100&&$intSum>-100?"0":"").substr_replace($paddedIntSum,".",-$numDecimals,0);
    return $result;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
echo decimalAdd("36.00","-35.99");
```

> 0.01

Comment: I don't think anyone can read your code easily. It's doing too much on each line and there's no spacing between operators or expressions.

Comment: I guess it could be made a little more easy to read. But looking at it a year after I wrote it I still have no problem with it whatsoever. The reason why I allowed myself to put that much on one line is that it's simply building the string from left to right with no nested function-calls or conditions or anything.