# Set precision for a float number in PHP

Tags: php, precision, rounding

I get a number from database and this number might be either `float` or `int`.


I need to set the decimal precision of the number to `3`, which makes the number not longer than (regarding decimals) `5.020` or `1518845.756`.

Using PHP

```
round($number, $precision)
```

I see a problem:

It rounds the number. I need a function to only cut the decimals short, without changing their values which `round( )` seems not to follow.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format) to achieve this:

```
echo number_format((float) $number, $precision, '.', '');
```

This would convert `1518845.756789` to `1518845.757`.

But if you just want to cut off the number of decimal places short to 3, and ***not* round**, then you can do the following:

```
$number = intval($number * ($p = pow(10, $precision))) / $p;
```

It may look intimidating at first, but the concept is really simple. You have a number, you multiply it by 10<sup>3</sup> (it becomes `1518845756.789`), cast it to an integer so everything after the 3 decimal places is removed (becomes `1518845756`), and then divide the result by 10<sup>3</sup> (becomes `1518845.756`).

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/174957)

Comment: This doesn't work if `intval($number * ($p …))` cannot be represented as an integer. For example: `$number = 10000000; $precision = 3;` results in `1410065.408` on a 32 bit machine.

Comment: @NisseEngström I don't know what are you doing, since you start with an integer and you end with nonsense...

Comment: @arod: That's *my* point. If *number* × *multiplier* is too large to be represented as an integer, then you end up with nonsense. On a 64-bit machine, you need larger numbers and precision to end up with nonsense values.

Comment: @NisseEngström: First solution is more preferable in such cases. Don't georgecj11's solution below have the same problem?

Answer (score 16):

Its sound like `floor` with decimals. So you can try something like

```
floor($number*1000)/1000
```

Comment: probably the fastest one?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you would not want rounding to occur and you would want the precision to be 3.

So the idea is to use [`number_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for a precision of 4 and then remove the last digit:

```
$number = '1518845.756789';
$precision = 3;

echo substr(number_format($number, $precision+1, '.', ''), 0, -1);
```

Will display:

```
1518845.756
```

rather than:

```
1518845.757
```

Links : [`number_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) , [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: This will not work if the 4th decimal is a `9` and the 5th decimal causes it to roll over. Try it with `$number = '0.00096'` for example.

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833137/how-to-make-number-format-not-to-round-numbers-up/55296506#55296506) for more details.

```
function numberPrecision($number, $decimals = 0)
{
    $negation = ($number < 0) ? (-1) : 1;
    $coefficient = pow(10, $decimals);
    return $negation * floor((string)(abs($number) * $coefficient)) / $coefficient;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$num=5.1239;
$testnum=intval($num*1000)/1000;
echo $testnum; //return 5.123
```