# phpmyadmin and dreamweaver 2 decimal place

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, dreamweaver

I have just created a database with phpmyadmin and made some pages to view edit and add to this database. One of the field is for money so needs to be to 2 decimal places it is set to a float, but when I enter say `1.20` and add it using the add record page I created and then go back to view it to is says `1.2` does any one know if I have to change any thing the web pages or the data base.

Comment: do **NOT** use floats for money values. if you want to store money, then use `decimal`, or convert your money into cents and use an int.

Comment: Look at my answer bellow, you might find some good pratices. :)

Comment: @MarcB thanks this work but had to change it to `2,2` can you post as a answer so that i can expect it

Comment: @Jhondoe I posted the solution you are looking for. cheers `bcdiv()`

Comment: don't forget to validate the answer, cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this example to format numbers

```
$foo = "105";
echo number_format((float)$foo, 2, '.', '');  // Outputs -> 105.00
```

Comment: where to in  php my admin or the web page? @ErasmoOliveira

Comment: @Jhondoe use in .php file, while printing the value in view, not in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Number_format()` with the precision `2`, and a separator `.`

with this syntax

```
echo number_format((float) $number, $precision, '.', '');
```

as shown on this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19875617/3871208)

it provides a very good demo

**IMPROVEMENT**

For money transaction it is better to save all the numbers in `INT` format then convert them into cents once you want to output them you just divide by Hundred.

Illustration:

`1.20` is saved as `120` then when it comes to output you just divide by 100 with the function bcdiv() as follow.

`echo bcdiv('120', '100', 2);`

**result**

`1.20`