# Add 0 To Last Decimal If Number < 10 PHP

Tags: php

I have the following variable in PHP:

```
$number = 1714.2
```

As you can see with the last decimal I would like to add a 0 if the last decimal number is lower than 10.

What I would like my variable to look like:

```
1714.02
```

Comment: [number_format](http://php.net/number_format). Though why would 1714.2 become 1714.02 instead of 1714.20?

Comment: `.02` and `.2` are not the same, you should store __the correct__ value.

Comment: the last digit will always be lower than 10 because thats how decimal/base 10 works

Answer (score 0):

**as .2 and .02 is not same. so, you must have to take correct value form source**

or maybe php-manual *number format* is helpful to you. http://php.net/number_format

Answer (score 0):

1714.2 is not equal to 1714.02
1714.2 means 1714.20 which means 1714.200

But if you want to get the desire result you want just put this code:

$number = $number - 0.18;

If you have a typo and you tried to say:

1714.2 being shown as 1714.20 then refer to:
[Set precision for a float number in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875583/set-precision-for-a-float-number-in-php) and [number_format](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)