# How to multiply a decimal number in PHP and get a result with decimal places

Tags: php, operators

I have the following code which multiplies a number (number is stored in a database) and I then download the result to a CSV file. The resulting number is given as a whole number rather than including a decimal place.

**Current Code**

```
<? return ((float) $amount*1) ?>
```

**Current Result:** 2 x 2.13 = 4

**Desired Result:** 2 x 2.13 = 4.26

*In this example $amount = 2.13*

Can anyone please suggest an edit to get this working?

Comment: How do you use that returned result? Can you share some more of the relevant code, the function (I assume since you `return`?) and how you use it?

Comment: Sounds similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875583/set-precision-for-a-float-number-in-php

Comment: Did you open it with a text editor or some spreadsheet  application ? The formating of the app might have something to do with it

Comment: This question makes no sense, really...

Comment: frz3993 I know it's not formatting as other values I pull from db that don't have a calculation show the decimal. FirstOne I am multiplying a decimal and receive a result that is not a decimal, as per above example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for that:

```
number_format(2.13 * 2, 2); // "4.26"
```

See https://3v4l.org/GlARW for performance related information.

Comment: If its a float, you can just echo the result directly, unless you want a specific amount of decimals - the `number_format()` isn't needed. https://3v4l.org/QOp91