# Using PHP floatval adds undesired trailing numbers behind decimal places

Tags: php, precision

I am having a problem with php conversion from string to float

In some cases, if I do:

```
floatval("8.80")
```

I get:

```
8.800000000000001
```

I have struggled with round(x,1), number_format, etc, but to no avail

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: This will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875583/set-precision-for-a-float-number-in-php

Comment: What are you using to "print" this value?  `var_export()`, `pring_r()`, `echo`, `var_dump()` something else?

Comment: Also worth a read: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14587290/2943403

Comment: Learn about floating point numbers here: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using number_format will help to resolve your issue

```
<?php
    $number = 8.800000000000001;
    $precision = 1;
    $number = intval($number * ($p = pow(10, $precision))) / $p;
    echo number_format((float) $number, $precision, '.', ''); 
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have same issuer, cast in string with number_format ou bcmath library work for display. But if you do a calcul, same problem.

```
<?php
    $number = 8.800000000000001;
    $precision = 1;
    $number = intval($number * ($p = pow(10, $precision))) / $p;
    echo (float)number_format((float) $number, $precision, '.', '');
?>
```

This give the same bad result

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34140595)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You need to set the "precision" PHP variable ("serialize_precision" pour php8) to 14 or more

```
ini_set("precision",17);
```

or

```
ini_set("serialize_precision",17);
```