# Shorten currency values like $20000 to $20k

Tags: php, numbers, currency

I'd like to convert currency values like this:

```
4 000 000 000 => 4b
2 000 000 => 2m
2 250 000 => 2.25m
195 000 => 195k
10 000 => 10k
```

Anyone know of an existing library/function that does this, or do I need to write this myself by means of conditionals that cater for 0-9999, 10000-999999, and so on..?

Comment: You can probably just count the zeroes, and divide by three to get a value to map to K, M, etc. Watch out for billion though - I think the number of zeroes on that is dependent on territory. Doesn't the US regard that as million million? (Edit: [it's changed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1,000,000,000)).

Comment: Not the US, no: they use the "short scale". You need distinguish between "short scale" and "long scale": not just billion is affected. I recall that currency *always* uses the short scale but can't find a citation: perhaps I've imagined that.

Comment: (Explaining the likely reason for the downvotes: we have a longstanding policy of showing what you have tried).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom function for this. The below one, firstly removes everything but numbers from string. Then it formats the number according how big is it and to the digit provided.

```
function shorten($num, $digits = 1) {
    $num = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$num);
    if ($num >= 1000000000) {
        $num = number_format(($num / 1000000000), $digits, '.', '') + 0;
        $num = $num . "b";
    }
    if ($num >= 1000000) {
        $num = number_format(($num / 1000000), $digits, '.', '') + 0;
        $num = $num . 'm';
    }
    if ($num >= 1000) {
        $num = number_format(($num / 1000), $digits, '.', '') + 0;
        $num = $num . 'k';
    }
    return $num;
}

echo shorten("4 000 000 000");
echo shorten("3 200 000 000");
echo shorten("195 000");
```

**Demo:** http://codepad.org/K971MzVx

Comment: Thanks @Burak. This is so close... One small thing is when I shorten 17000, I get 17.0k. This is right when the value is 17500 for example, but if its a zero, it should just be 17k

Comment: Likewise if I do 70000, it returns 70.0k

Comment: edited the answer according to that, just add zero to the number, then you are fine.

Comment: if I use 3750000 it becomes 3.8m. Is there a way to have it *not* round up?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833137/how-to-make-number-format-not-to-round-numbers-up

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function like this to display shorten the values but it would miss the exact value

```
function shortifyCurrency($var){
  $var=doubleval($var);
  if($var>=1000000000){
    $var=($var/1000000000)."b";
  }else if($var>=1000000){
    $var=($var/1000000)."m";
  }else if($var>=1000){
    $var=($var/1000)."k";
  }
  return $var;
}
//Output 4b
echo shortifyCurrency(4000000000);
```

Or you could use the following function to display more detailed information about the value

```
function shortifyCurrencyXtream($var){
  $var=doubleval($var);
  $print_str="";

  if($var>=1000000000){
    $print_str.=round($var/1000000000)."b";
    $var=$var%1000000000;
  }
  if($var>=1000000){
    if($print_str!="") $print_str.=" ";
    $print_str.=round($var/1000000)."m";
    $var=$var%1000000;
  }
  if($var>=1000){
    if($print_str!="") $print_str.=" ";
    $print_str.=($var/1000)."k";
  }
  return $print_str;
}
//Output 4b 101m 500.3k
echo shortifyCurrencyXtream(4100500300);
```

Comment: you can round the numbers after division if you want to