# Am I expecting number_format to do something it is not meant to do?

Tags: php, number-formatting

I have a float: 9.174599999999995

Which when I run number_format(9.174599999999995, 2) I am getting 9.17. I believe I should be getting 9.18 as the 4 rounds up to 5 and then the 7 rounds to 8. Is this not right? How can I achieve the desired result of 9.18?

Comment: 9.174599999999995 rounds to 9.17, not 9.18.

Comment: No its not. Any number  less than 5 will round down to 0 which is why you get 17 and not 18.

Comment: thats not how rounding works, in maths regardless of php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833137/how-to-make-number-format-not-to-round-numbers-up

Answer (score 0):

This is because `number_format` doesn't round :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Take a look at `round` function :
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.round.php

Answer (score 0):

Well, you assume wrong, the correct answer is 9.17, because the rounding is made based on just one digit after the rounding point.
Basically when you round 9.174599999999995 with 2 decimals, you round it based on 4, which is smaller than 5, so the number is rounded to 9.17

Answer (score 0):

due to case you can use php round. 
Examples:

```
$n=3.18925

$round=round($round, 1);
```

it will be displayed 3.2

```
$round=round($round, 2);
```

it will be displayed 3.19

Answer (score 0):

For your number,

```
$number = 9.17499999999995 ;
echo $english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
9.17

$number = 9.17599999999995 ;
echo $english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
9.18
```

and by using number_format for 2 times you can achieve desire result

```
$number = 9.17499999999995 ;
echo $number = number_format($number, 3, '.', '');
echo "<br>";
echo $english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');  

RESULTS    
    9.175
    9.18
```